# How to add headers when connecting to a websocket in Haskell

Tags: haskell, websocket, mtgox

I'm trying to create a WebSocket client to connect to an existing server ([mtgox api](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/Streaming)).

As a starting point, to figure out connecting to WebSockets, I found this example code https://github.com/jaspervdj/websockets/blob/master/example/client.hs

The problem is that Mtgox requires headers to be sent along when it connects, I'm just not sure how to send them.

**Update:** To help work this out, I created a simple websocket server too. When I connect to it via a JavaScript WebSocket from my Chrome JavaScript console, I see the following headers:

```
 requestHeaders = [("Upgrade","websocket"),("Connection","Upgrade"),
("Host","127.0.0.1:8001"),("Origin","chrome://newtab"),("Pragma","no-cache"),
("Cache-Control","no-cache"),("Sec-WebSocket-Key","yOsPEMHx9AyT9u3ssNma/Q=="),
("Sec-WebSocket-Version","13"),("Sec-WebSocket-Extensions","x-webkit-deflate-frame"),
("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36")]
```

Whereas, when I connect through via the Haskell client, I see only the following headers:

```
requestHeaders = [("Host","127.0.0.1"),("Connection","Upgrade"),
("Upgrade","websocket"),("Sec-WebSocket-Key","X3hMDW4fAau53dbz7w4MTw=="),
("Sec-WebSocket-Version","13")]
```

I don't know which of the headers are actually required by MtGox, but my plan was to just send the same ones that Chrome sends, since that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `connect` I used `connectWith`, which allows the "Origin" header to be set. Although I can't see how to add any other headers, this is the one that MtGox requires. As long as I provide an origin, with some kind of http-based url, it connects successfully.

```
WS.connectWith "websocket.mtgox.com" 80 "/mtgox" (Just "http://anything") Nothing app
```

It would seem that it is mostly unnecessary to add any further headers, and presumably that is why no mechanism is provided. However, looking at the [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/websockets/0.7.3.0/doc/html/src/Network-WebSockets-Client.html#connectWithSocket), it's possible by copy-pasting the code of `connectWith` and `connectWithSocket` to change the headers that are added to the Request object.

Answer (score 0):

According to the below answer it's not possible except for the WebSocket-Protocol header:
[HTTP headers in Websockets client API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361173/http-headers-in-websockets-client-api)

Comment: That question is about sending custom headers using Javascript WebSockets. There are some standard headers that are added automatically when you use a JavaScript client, and the MtGox api requires these.