# SAPUI5 WebSocket authentication

Tags: websocket, sapui5

I have created a service in SAP backend that serves for websocket connections. I wanna connect to that service from SAPUI5 application. I connect to the service like this:

```
sap.ui.require("sap/ui/core/ws/WebSocket");
        var socket = new WebSocket(
                'ws://<host>:<port>/sap/bc/apc/sap/z_reg_test_push_ch');
```

When this piece of code is called I get:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://<host>:<port>/sap/bc/apc/sap/z_reg_test_push_ch' failed: HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available
```

When I test the service from backend it will open the service url in chrome and asks me for credentials. Then when I refresh the UI5 app the webservice connection is established because the user has already logged in the same session in chrome when testing the service from backend.

In SAPUI5 app I can access the security token which was returned when connecting to oData service. I can access is like this:

```
var oModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel();
oModel.getSecurityToken();
```

the token looks like this: `cKYPxpo7-BELSah1D1WRgg==`

I have found [a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383089/is-it-possible-to-use-bearer-authentication-for-websocket-upgrade-requests/26123316#26123316) that I should create the websocket connection like this:

```
new WebSocket('ws://<host>:<port>/sap/bc/apc/sap/z_reg_test_push_ch',["access_token", oModel.getSecurityToken()]);
```

But I get this message:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The subprotocol 'cKYPxpo7-BELSah1D1WRgg==' is invalid.
```

To sum it up. I am authenticated by the oData service via basic auth and I want to pass to the socket the authentication info.

Comment: I don't think it works that way, `getSecurityToken` returns the csrf token, not the bearer token

Comment: So how should I pass credentials to the websocket?

Comment: I honestly don’t know. The actual values are in one of the cookies

Comment: I just remembered there’s a thing called ABAP Channels. I think it’s just a socket implementation / wrapper. There are some blogs on using it with UI5.

Comment: Yeah, I went trough all the tutorials and documentation and no one really explained how to authenticate the WebSocket. For them it somehow just worked.

Comment: Because the UI5 helpers might do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that to pass user credentials to the ICF service, you have to create the websocket like this:

```
new WebSocket('ws://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<path_to_service>')
```

This, however, raises a security problem, since the connection is not secured, so every one can read the user credentials.

But I did not find any other solution of the authenticate a user.