# How to Pass Authorization Bearer Token in Websocket API

Tags: kubernetes, websocket, xtermjs

I'm trying to exec kubernetes pod using the Websocket, as per the kubernetes document it can be achieved through passing the  **Bearer THETOKEN**

When using bearer token authentication from an http client, the API server expects an Authorization header with a value of Bearer THETOKEN

Here is the sample for `wscat` passing Header Value `--header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"` to establish exec to pod and the connection  went successfully

```
/ # wscat  --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"  -c "wss://api.0cloud0.com/api/v1/namespaces/ba410a7474380169a5ae230d8e784535/pods/txaclqhshg
-6f69577c74-jxbwn/exec?stdin=1&stdout=1&stderr=1&tty=1&command=sh"
```

But when it comes to [Websocket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) connection from web browser

> How to pass this Beaer Token in the web Socket as per the doc there is no standard way to pass custom header

Tried URI Query Parameter **access_token= Bearer TOKEN** in the API query it doesn't work and the Authentication denied with 403

```
wss://api.0cloud0.com/api/v1/namespaces/ba410a7474380169a5ae230d8e784535/pods/txaclqhshg-%206f69577c74-jxbwn/exec?stdout=1&stdin=1&stderr=1&tty=1&command=%2Fbin%2Fsh&command=-i&access_token=$TOKEN
```

Comment: A question similar to this exists [is it possible to use bbearer authentication for websocket upgrade request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383089/is-it-possible-to-use-bearer-authentication-for-websocket-upgrade-requests/26123316#26123316)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pod exec (and run a command) using Kubernetes API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76119545/how-can-i-pod-exec-and-run-a-command-using-kubernetes-api)

Answer (score 1):

I never used websocket with kubernetes before, but here is the documentation about the token authentication method for websocket browser clients https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/47740

You must to send token in subprotocol parameter with the token encoded in base64.

So it should be:

```
wscat  -s "base64url.bearer.authorization.k8s.io.$TOKEN_IN_BASE64","base64.binary.k8s.io" -c "wss://api.0cloud0.com/api/v1/namespaces/ba410a7474380169a5ae230d8e784535/pods/txaclqhshg
-6f69577c74-jxbwn/exec?stdin=1&stdout=1&stderr=1&tty=1&command=sh"
```