# Can we add header information to web socket sampler in JMeter?

Tags: java, websocket, jmeter

I am getting following error when I was using my localhost url and ws protocol

```
[Problems] - Unexpected error: null
JMeter.plugins.functional.samplers.websocket.ServiceSocket.sendMessage(ServiceSocket.java:156)
JMeter.plugins.functional.samplers.websocket.WebSocketSampler.sample(WebSocketSampler.java:136)
org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

there is no way to add header information like in http sampler in JMeter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361173/http-headers-in-websockets-client-api

Answer (score 4):

You can add the headers in JMeter for WS. Right click on the sampler > Add > Config Element > HTTP Header Manager.