# Why is there no same-origin policy for WebSockets? Why can I connect to ws://localhost?

Tags: javascript, security, websocket

I'd like to use WebSockets for inter-process communication for my application (Daemon<->WebGUI and Daemon<->FatClient, etc.). During testing, I tried connecting to my locally running web socket server (ws://localhost:1234) via the JavaScript WebSocket client on websocket.org (http://www.websocket.org/echo.html).

My question now is:
**Why is this possible?** Is there no cross-origin policy implemented in the browsers (here: FF29 on Linux)?

I am asking because if websocket.org was evil, it could try to communicate with my local WS server and redirect every message it receives from localhost to any other server:

```
Local WebSocket Server            Browser            Evil Web Server
at ws://localhost:1234                               at http://evil.tld
        |                            |                       |
        |                            |------[GET /]--------->|
        |                            |<-----[HTML+EvilJS]----|
        |<------[connect ws://..]----|                       |
        |<----[some communication]-->|                       |
        |                            |----[evil forward]---->|
        |                            |                       |
```

I have not tested the entire use case, but the connect to ws://localhost from the JS delivered by websocket.org definitely works.

Comment: websocket.org should not be evil, Web sockets can be ;)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

To address the "Why?" part, the reason why browsers don't enforce the Same Origin Policy (of which CORS is a relaxation) for WebSockets as opposed to AJAX calls, is because WebSockets were introduced after the value of cross-origin requests was established, and because they're not subject to SOP to begin with, the historical reason for the CORS client-side checks doesn't apply.

For AJAX, in the days of a blanket Single Origin Policy, servers never expected an authenticated browser to send a request from a different domain<sup>1</sup>, and so didn't need to ensure the request was coming from a trusted location<sup>2</sup>, just check the session cookie. Later relaxations like CORS had to have client-side checks to avoid [exposing existing applications to abuse](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0) by violating this assumption (effectively doing a [CSRF attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)).

If the Web were being invented today, knowing what we know now, neither SOP nor CORS would be required for AJAX and it's possible that all the validation would be left to the server.

WebSockets, being a newer technology, are designed to support cross-domain scenarios from the get go. Anyone writing server logic should be aware of the possibility of cross-origin requests and perform the necessary validation, without the need for heavy-handed browser-side precautions à la CORS.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is a simplification. Cross-origin GET requests for resources (including <img>, <link> and <script> tags) and form submission POST requests were always permitted as a fundamental feature of the Web. Nowadays, cross-origin AJAX calls whose requests have the same properties are also permitted and known as [simple cross-origin requests](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#simple-cross-origin-request). However, accessing the returned data from such requests in code is not allowed unless explicitly permitted by the server's CORS headers. Also, it is these "simple" POST requests that are the primary reason why anti-CSRF tokens are necessary for servers to protect themselves from malicious websites.

<sup>2</sup> In fact, a secure way to check the request source wasn't even available since the `Referer` header can be spoofed e.g. using an open redirect vulnerability. This also shows how poorly CSRF vulnerabilities were understood back then.

Comment: This does indeed answer the question, so +1. But, for the record, I strongly disagree with this reasoning. I predict that as a result of this design decision, a significant number of sites which use WebSockets will fail to validate the `Origin` header and leak private user data to third party sites as a result. Clients checking the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, as they do before allowing JS access to the responses to any other cross-origin HTTP request on the web, would have been a simple way to prevent this entire class of attack (Cross-Site WebSocket Hijacking). Too late now.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree, the design change is essentially moving from a whitelist-based approach to a blacklist one, which is risky. Fair point.

Answer (score 45):

[oberstet answered the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674199/why-is-there-no-same-origin-policy-for-websockets-why-can-i-connect-to-ws-loc#comment36372038_23674863). Thank you! Unfortunately I can't mark it as "correct" because it was a comment. The browser sends the "origin" header which can be checked by the application.

In Java [1]:

```
@Override
public void onOpen(WebSocket clientSocket, ClientHandshake handshake) {
    String clientOrigin = handshake.getFieldValue("origin");

    if (clientOrigin == null || !clientOrigin.equals(WEBSOCKET_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_HEADER)) {
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Client did not sent correct origin header: " + clientOrigin);        

        clientSocket.close();
        return;
    }

    // ...
}
```

[1] using https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket

Comment: OWASP mentions checking the Origin (and potentially the Referer) header in their [CSRF cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) as the first and most important step, but they also recommend going a step further and implementing a CSRF specific defense. In the case of WebSockets, this might be appending an XSRF antiforgery token to the WS URI as a query parameter and validating it server-side after the origin check.

Comment: Checking the `Origin` header is nice, but nothing more as the `Origin` header itself is merely advisory. Any non-browser client (e.g. curl) can send arbitrary `Origin`.

Answer (score 20):

WebSockets can cross domain communication, and they are not limited by the SOP (Same Origin Policy).

The same security issue you described can happen without WebSockets.

The evil JS can:

- Create a script/image tag with a URL to evil.tld and put data in the query string.
- Create a form tag, put the data in the fields, and invoke the "submit" action of the form, doing an HTTP POST, that can be cross domain. AJAX is limited by the SOP, but normal HTTP POST is not. Check the XSRF web security issue.

If something injects javascript in your page, or you get malicious javascript, your security is already broken.

Comment: I am not worried about the evil JS. I know that this is always possible. What I am really concerned about is the browser-breakout: Any website can now communicate with a *locally* bound WS socket and steal data from there.

Comment: SOP/CORS does not apply to WebSocket, but browsers will send an `origin` header that contains the hostname of the server that served the HTML with the JS that opened the WebSocket connection. A WebSocket server can then restrict access by checking `origin`.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question was why a _webpage from a different domain_  can access a local WebSocket. In OPs scenario there is nothing that "injects javascript in your page" - that is a different scenario. Without WebSocket, a remote webpage would not be able to read resources on localhost, because that is precisely what the SOP prevents.

Comment: @oberstet Could you offer a link like `https://w3.org/TR/CSS2` for CSS  to verify the content above?

Comment: @liuliang checkout "Origin" in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.6 and other sections