# Django restframework, Django channels, Ionic 2 - websocket handshake error

Tags: django, ionic-framework, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers, django-channels

I am currently working on a project using the technologies mentioned in the thread title.

I got it all running from the browser (the application is hosted on heroku), but when I try to connect to the websockets from my Ionic 2 application, I always get an error establishing handshake.

```
2016-09-17T15:02:03.200133+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-09-17 15:02:03,199 DEBUG    Connection http.response!uvRVDyvolYEG did not get successful WS handshake.

2016-09-17T15:02:03.200498+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-09-17 15:02:03,200 DEBUG    WebSocket closed before handshake established

2016-09-17T15:02:03.169206+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/1/" host=musicmashup-jukebox.herokuapp.com request_id=c46960d7-bb8f-45bf-b8be-5a934c771d96 fwd="212.243.230.222" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=400 bytes=74
```

Now one idea was, that it could be a CORS problem. So I installed `django-cors-middleware` in hope this could solve the problem - well it did not.
But I think the app does not add any headers to the Daphne server at all.

At the moment I have no idea anymore, if the problem is on the client or on the server side.

Has anyone experienced similar problems?

EDIT:
Found out that websockets and CORS do not have anything to do with each other [Why is there no same-origin policy for WebSockets? Why can I connect to ws://localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674199/why-is-there-no-same-origin-policy-for-websockets-why-can-i-connect-to-ws-loc#comment36372038_23674863)
So my guess is, that the server may reject the origin header sent by the client. I will see if I can get my hands on the headers being sent

Comment: some more technical details on websockets and the use of the origin header http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/115716/is-the-origin-header-really-useful-for-securing-a-websocket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed in Daphne v.1.0.3
https://github.com/django/daphne/commit/07dd777ef11f5091931fbb22bdacb9e4aefea7da

You need to also update channels and asgi-redis if it's used.

Comment: Did not try this, but it looks like this might be the best answer to date. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the problem was somehow related to the origin header. Ionic seems to be sending a origin header containing "file://..", which was getting rejected / blocked by the websocket server.

Unfortunately I did not find a way to configure the webserver on heroku to either ignore this or set another origin header on incoming packets.

My Procfile on heroku:

```
web: daphne app.asgi:channel_layer --port $PORT--bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
worker: python manage.py runworker -v2
```

What I did then, was moving the whole application to a self hosted Ubuntu server and putting an nginx in front of Daphne, where I created a rule to override the origin header of incoming packets.

That's how it can be done.. I hope this can help some people.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you platzhersch,

it worked for me with the following nginx rule:

```
proxy_set_header Origin http://$host;
```