# What is the websocket url of my AWS EC2 Instance?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, django-channels

I have successfully implemented a chat system using Django Channels. I am trying to deploy it to my EC2 Instance. I am reading the [official channels documentation](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploying.html#example-setups) and also following other tutorials. Before daemonising daphne and adding a proxy pass. I wanted to run it manually so I ran the following command.

```
$ daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 5000 instagram.asgi:application

INFO     Starting server at tcp:port=5000:interface=0.0.0.0
INFO     HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
INFO     Configuring endpoint tcp:port=5000:interface=0.0.0.0
INFO     Listening on TCP address 0.0.0.0:5000
```

```
# chat/routing.py
from django.urls import re_path

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^ws/chat/(?P<room_name>[\w-]+)/', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

```
#asgi.py
"""
ASGI config for instagram project.

It exposes the ASGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/asgi/
"""

import os
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
import chat.routing
from instagram.ChatJWTAuth import JWTAuthMiddleware

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'instagram.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
  "http": get_asgi_application(),
  "websocket": JWTAuthMiddleware(
        URLRouter(
            chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

Comment: Can you access your site on your EC2 Instance over http/https: `http(s)://<instance_ip>:5000`? The websocket address is just a different protocol: `ws(s)://<instance_ip>:5000`

Comment: You would need to access your application using the public ip of your EC2 instance with the port number which is 5000 in your case. Also, you would need to allow traffic on your port 5000 in the inbound rules of your instance's security group. Then you can access your application like - http://<instance-ip>:<application-port>

Comment: @IainShelvington No I cannot... Here is my public ip address. http://65.1.114.5/

Comment: What is this `instagram.ChatJWTAuth.JWTAuthMiddleware`?

Comment: @KavishBaghel I know its bad practice but its just for a personal project. I have set inbound rules to allow all ip and ports. http://65.1.114.5/ here is my public ip address. Unfortunately on port 5000 its returning Error 404.

Comment: @IainShelvington That is my the asgi middleware I am using to decode jwt tokens.

Comment: Its returning 404 because you have not configured any routing on the / url in django. If you access something like /admin you will land on the django admin page - http://65.1.114.5:5000/admin/

Comment: @GuruRandapa Try `ws://65.1.114.5/ws/chat/foo/`?

Comment: Also you should only allow port 5000 and that too only for your ip even if you are testing. Just go to the inbound rules of the security group and in port enter "5000" and in the source select "My IP". Hope this helps!

Comment: @IainShelvington No it is not working but as pointed out by Kavish Baghel. Requesting http://65.1.114.5:5000/admin/ is giving me a log on my ec2 log. So, I think thats the step in the right direction. Thank You Very Much!

Comment: @KavishBaghel Do I also need to configure any urls beside routing.py?

Comment: @GuruRandapa What url and protocol you need to get working?

Comment: @KavishBaghel I need to get the websocket protocol working... For my local system ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/chat/1-2/ works well. where 1-2 is my room_name. I wonder what equivalent of this would be in ec2.

Comment: This would be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548817/django-restframework-django-channels-ionic-2-websocket-handshake-error