# Invalid Origin Header

Tags: python, websocket

I'm trying to make a websocket connection but am getting the error:

> Incorrect origin in request header.

My code is:

```
def create_signature():
    timestamp = int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()) 
    string = "{}{}".format(timestamp, key)
    return timestamp, hmac.new(secret.encode(), string.encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
def auth_request():
    timestamp, signature = create_signature()
    return json.dumps({'e': 'auth',
        'auth': {'key': key, 'signature': signature, 'timestamp': timestamp}})

def main():
    ws = create_connection(websocketURL)
    authentication = auth_request()
    ws.send(authentication)
    result = ws.recv()
    print(result)
    ws.close()
```

I'm running the `main` function. `auth_request` returns a valid json. I'm trying to get a valid response object but the connection fails. I've imported the relevant libraries and don't have any syntax errors. All the variables are defined in another file.

How do I fix this issue, it's my first time using web sockets?

Comment: The code itself is probably fine - the issue is the request origin header, and CSRF/CORS-like behaviour - i.e the server is denying requests that come from diffeerent/untrusted domains. See https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-abarth-origin-03.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS for some background on the http implementation of this type of checking..

Comment: Why is it an HTTP CORS issue, isn't the whole point of web sockets to be using TCP instead of HTTP?

Comment: @WMios: No; that would break the entire security model of the web.  Web Sockets is an HTTP-like protocol with similar restrictions.

Comment: @WMios: I believe it might not be implemented as CORS, but serves can look at the origin and choose to deny ones from different domains. Will update comment to clarify.

Comment: @SLaks, ah thanks, I didn't realize that! How in python do you implement websocket headers?

Comment: @match, I saw this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674199/why-is-there-no-same-origin-policy-for-websockets-why-can-i-connect-to-ws-loc, I'm confused as to why I would need something CORS like.

Comment: The server is free to decide what origins to accept or reject - in this case it doesn't like the origin of your client. It would require server configuration modification to change this.  I was mistaken that websockets used CORS - they don't use the specific CORS protocol, but the server receives the origin and is free to act upon it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your code is from www.cex.io. (If it is not, Sorry)

In order to work with cex.io ws api you need to state correct *Origin header* when connecting to websocket:
`Origin: wss.cex.io` (I personally asked this question to cex.io support team)

And for market data(ticker, ohlcv..), you will not need to auth
`https://gist.github.com/icehongssii/1c8ec1755dfee88c2789714ee9a37738.js`

Comment: No longer working on the project, but thanks - it was for cex. Had really terrible documentation 6 months ago.

Comment: @WMios Yes, I totally agree with that they have such a terrible documentation. And their support was not that helpful. Even I point out their code, they did not fix it either.