# How To Prevent Multiple Socket.io Event Listeners

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I need to be able to access req from my socket.io event listeners. So I did this:

Server

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),

app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

client = require('socket.io').listen(8080).sockets;

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    client.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log("Connection")
    });
    res.render('chat');
});

app.listen(config.server.port, function() {
    console.log("Listening on port " + config.server.port);
});
```

Client:

```
try {
        var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080');

    } catch(e) {
        //Set status to warn user
        console.log(e);
    }
```

The problem is that if you add socket.io event listeners inside of an express route handler multiple listeners are created on the socket. If you were to create the pug file and test this code you would notice the console logging "connection" once on first refresh twice on second and so on because each time the route is handled another event listener is being added. I could fix it by moving the listener outside of the route handler however I need to be able to access "req". Is there any solution to this that would allow me to access "req" and prevent excess listeners from being added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `req` object accessed in the socket.io `connection` event listener is the `req` when the event listener is declared, NOT the `req` when the event listener is executed. Thus, the expected behavior mentioned in the question (if my understanding is correct) is impossible.

Here is a simple experiment, for the code in question:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  client.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("req.url: " + req.url)
  });
  res.render('chat');
});
```

If browser is used to send 2 HTTP request: first `GET /?q=42` and then `GET /?q=88`, the `console.log` result would be:

```
//first request
req.url: /?q=42

//second request
req.url: /?q=42
req.url: /?q=88
```

For the second request, as `connection` event is listened twice, the event listener would be executed twice too. However, the execution result is different -- the event listener attached in the first HTTP request *remember* the `req` object value at that time.

---

If there is only one client, and no concurrent requests (a very restricted situation), there is a workaround -- save `req` as `currentReq`, and make event listener deal with `currentReq`:

```
var currentReq;
var isListened = false;

// write logic in middleware, so it can be used in all routes.
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  currentReq = req;
  if (!isListened) {
    client.on('connection', function (socket) {
      console.log("req.url: " + currentReq.url)
    });
    isListened = true;
  }
  next();
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('chat');
});
```

---

Here is some thinking about why this is impossible.

The scenario in the question is:

1. Browser send HTTP `GET` request to Node.js
2. Node.js return HTML page to browser
3. Browser parse and render HTML page
4. Browser send WebSocket connection request to Node.js
5. Node.js establish WebSocket connection, and print log on console.

It is clear that when `connection` event happens (step 5), the HTTP `req` (step 1) has long gone. There is no way to restore initial HTTP request information in step 5, as WebSocket and HTTP are different connection, on different port.

Comment: If this isn't possible, then how can I determine if a user is logged into my site or not inside of the listener. As of right now I just check if req.user exists and if is does then I know they are logged in. I want certain socket events to make sure the user is signed in before handling them.

Comment: @Undying to determine whether a user is logged in or not, you can send JWT token or session id as query param in WebSocket connection. In this way, when WebSocket event listener is triggered, the JWT token can be decoded to check whether user is still logged in. Or, when WebSocket event listener is triggered, session id is used to check whether the session is still valid.

Comment: @Undying please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31680641/passing-jwt-to-node-js-websocket-in-authorization-header-on-initial-connection for some previous discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the recorded event listeners by console logging the `io.sockets`

```
Namespace {
  _events:
   { connection: [ [Function], [Function], [Function], [Function] ] },
  _eventsCount: 1 }
```

To fix your problem, simply put this condition before you initialize the socket connection

```
  if(io.sockets._events == undefined) {
    io.on('connection', socket => {
      ...
    });
  }
```

In case there are other event listeners aside from `connection`

```
  if(!('connection' in io.sockets._events)) {
    io.on('connection', socket => {
      ...
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but it seems like OP wants to access the req object to verify login. To add my 2 pennies to the mix, this is what I've done in a similar situation:

With my app using cookie based login tokens (over https only!), I was able to access the login cookie using

```js
function cookieParser(cookief) {
    let cookies = {}
    let _cookies = cookief.split("; ")
    for(cookiekv of cookief.split("; ")) {
        let kv = cookiekv.split("=")
        cookies[kv[0]] = kv[1]
    }
    return cookies
}
function verifyLogin(cookies) {
    //verify login cookies here. Change this example
    return cookies.loginToken
}
io.use(function(socket,next) {
    const cookies = cookieParser(socket.handshake.headers.cookie)
    if(verifyLogin(cookies)) {
        next()
    } else {
        next(new Error("invalid login token"))
    } 
})
```

This allowed me to only accept socket connections from users that have logged in and received a login token. This should also fix your multiple listeners scenario since only one listener is registered on `io`.

Hope this helps out!