# OAuth2 Authentication for Websockets: Pass Bearer Token via Subprotocols?

Tags: websocket, oauth-2.0

I am trying to figure out what the best way is to pass an oauth bearer token to a websocket endpoint.

[This SO answer suggests to send the token in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338883/javascript-websocket-client-library-which-can-pass-custom-headers-in-handshake-r),
however this approach has all the drawbacks of authenticating via the URL. Security implications discussed [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.3)

Thus i was wondering what would be the drawbacks to use the subprotocols to pass the token to the server ? i.e. instead of treating the requested subprotocols as a list of constants. Send at least one subprotocol that follows a syntax like for example: `authorization-bearer-<token>`

The token would end up in a request header.
The server while processing the subprotocols would be able to find and treat the token easily with a bit of custom code.
Since passing subprotocols should be supported by a lot of websocket implementations, this should work for a lot of clients.

Comment: Very interesting idea this. Could anyone comment that is more deeply involved in that?

Comment: I found one other approach in this project: https://github.com/tmc/grpc-websocket-proxy syntax is slightly different: `Sec-Websocket-Protocol: Bearer, foobar` means `Authorization: Bearer foobar`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, I used this [WebSocket client library](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client).

You need to send OAUTH token via the Websocket Header, Below is the code, hope this is helpful.

```
ws = factory.createSocket("wss://yourcompleteendpointURL/");
ws.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer <yourOAUTHtoken>");
ws.addHeader("Upgrade", "websocket");
ws.addHeader("Connection", "Upgrade");
ws.addHeader("Host", "<YourhostURLasabovegiveupto.com>");
ws.addHeader("Sec-WebSocket-Key", "<Somerandomkey>");
ws.addHeader("Sec-WebSocket-Version", "13");
ws.connect();
```