# How to send token within url in Kubernetes?

Tags: websocket, kubernetes

I want to use websocket to access Kubernetes API, and so it is more convenient to send token like `wss://example.com" + url + "&access_token=blahblahblah`. The official API doc sends token in header. Where can I find such a token and send it with url?

What I want to do is to exec pods via a web page through websocket:

[Container-Terminal via Websocket](https://github.com/kubernetes-ui/container-terminal)

[Support exec and pod logging over WebSockets](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/13885)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bearer token authentication in the URL is not supported in Kubernetes currently, only as an `Authorization` header.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to send `Authorization` headers using native javascript WebSockets.

- All third-party websocket libraries depend on the in-browser [`WebSocket`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) class, which currently does **not** support custom headers. I tried a bunch of different libraries, but no luck :(
- See Stack Overflow thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4361358
- The reason that this is not implemented is that Chromium/Chrome implementors are opposed to it. See the full discussion here: https://github.com/whatwg/websockets/issues/16#issuecomment-332065542

**My workaround**

Currently I'm working around this by using the [`@kubernetes/client-node`](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript) in NodeJS to open a WebSocket connection.

The `ws` WebSocket library in NodeJS does support Authorization headers.

Then forwarding the NodeJS WebSocket messages to the front-end using Socket.io: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62547135.

Answer (score 0):

After searching over the Internet and reading many discussion on Kubernetes, I post my own answer about accessing kubernetes API with password in url, not header:

wss://username:myPassword@Address.To.Kubernetes/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/YourPodName/exec?stdout=1&stdin=1&stderr=1&tty=1&command=%2Fbin%2Fsh

The username and password is in ~/.kube/config

Welcome answers for sending bearer token.

Comment: note that that is username/password auth, not bearer token auth

Comment: @JordanLiggitt Yes, and I am still waiting for answer using bearer token auth.