# How can I request the Gemini Order Events WebSocket from my Angular Nodejs web app?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, rxjs, http-headers

Headers are required for this third-party WebSocket according to the [Gemini documentation](https://docs.gemini.com/websocket-api/#order-events):

> Your WebSocket request needs to include these three headers:
> X-GEMINI-APIKEY
> X-GEMINI-PAYLOAD
> X-GEMINI-SIGNATURE

Python WebSocket connection example from the documentation:

```
import ssl
import websocket
...
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://api.gemini.com/v1/order/events",
                            on_message=on_message,
                            header={
                                'X-GEMINI-PAYLOAD': b64.decode(),
                                'X-GEMINI-APIKEY': gemini_api_key,
                                'X-GEMINI-SIGNATURE': signature
                            })
ws.run_forever(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})
```

**Important: I do not control this WebSocket server so I can't use server-side 'hacks'.**

I am able to successfully request this websocket from Google Cloud Functions using the NodeJS 'ws' library:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
exports.start_gemini_socket = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  var socket = new WebSocket(url, {headers:{myHeaders}});
}
```

I can also request a different Gemini WebSocket (no headers) directly from my TypeScript Angular web app using the 'RxJs' library.  This works as expected and flows into my web app, but it's a public WebSocket and doesn't require headers:

```
import { webSocket } from 'rxjs/webSocket'
this.connection$ = webSocket('wss://api.gemini.com/v1/marketdata/btcusd')
```

I understand browser-based websocket requests are not allowed to send headers:
Stack Overflow: [Custom headers for WebSocket JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853185/custom-headers-for-websocket-js#:%7E:text=Websocket%20client%20API%20doesn%27t,use%20token%20in%20query%20string.)
Stack Overflow: [HTTP headers in Websockets client API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361173/http-headers-in-websockets-client-api)

Is there a better solution to getting this data into my Angular web app?