# Why WebSocket connection with a server disconnects immediately after connection, how to ensure it keeps open?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, sockets, websocket, nuxt.js

I am developing a web socket connection from my front end to the server and the connection for some reason closes immediately after opening the connection. I am able to see that the same info works well in the Postman collection but for some reason, it fails in Nuxt 3 or the Vue-based app.

Also, I would like to know how to establish a connection to the server with the token, I have the token and I want to connect to my WebSocket with a token, how to achieve this?

I have the following code:

```
<template>
  <div class="flex items-center space-x-4">
    <div class="flex-1">
      <input
        v-model="socketUrl"
        placeholder="WebSocket URL"
        class="w-full p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-300 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-white"
        :disabled="isConnected"
      />
    </div>
    <button
      @click="toggleConnection"
      class="px-4 py-2 text-white rounded-md focus:outline-none dark:bg-green-600 dark:hover:bg-green-700 dark:focus:ring-2 dark:focus:ring-green-500"
      :class="[
        isConnected
          ? 'bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-600 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-red-500'
          : 'bg-green-700 hover:bg-green-800 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-300',
        'dark:bg-green-800',
      ]"
    >
      {{ isConnected ? "Disconnect" : "Connect" }}
    </button>
  </div>
</template>


<script setup>
const isConnected = ref(false);
const config = useRuntimeConfig();
const socketUrl = config.public.WS_URL;

// Component-specific logic
onMounted(() => {
  // Connect to WebSocket when the component is mounted
  connectWebSocket();

  // Start the ping mechanism
  startPing();
});

const toggleConnection = () => {
  if (isConnected.value) {
    disconnectWebSocket();
  } else {
    connectWebSocket();
  }
  isConnected.value = !isConnected.value;
};
</script>
```

`composables/socketConnection.js`:

```
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
const config = useRuntimeConfig();
const socketUrl = config.public.WS_URL;
const clientId = config.public.WS_CLIENT_ID;
const clientSecret = config.public.WS_CLIENT_SECRET;
const webSocket = ref(null);
const isConnected = ref(false);

export const connectWebSocket = () => {

    const completeSocketURL = socketUrl + "&Authorization=Bearer ";

    console.log(completeSocketURL);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("keycloakToken"))

    const socket = new WebSocket(completeSocketURL + localStorage.getItem("keycloakToken"));

    socket.onopen = function (event) {
        isConnected.value = true;
        console.log("Connection Opened : " + JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));
    };

    socket.onmessage = function (event) {
        console.log("WS Received Message : " + JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));
    };

    socket.onerror = function (event) {
        console.error("WS Error Received : " + JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));
    };

    socket.onclose = function (event) {
        isConnected.value = false;
        console.log("WS Disconnected : " + JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));
    };

    webSocket.value = socket;
};

export const disconnectWebSocket = () => {
    if (webSocket.value) {
        webSocket.value.close();
        isConnected.value = false;
    }
};

export const startPing = () => {
    // Send a ping message to the server every 30 seconds (adjust the interval as needed)
    const pingInterval = setInterval(() => {
        if (webSocket.value && webSocket.value.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        webSocket.value.send("ping");
        }
    }, 30000);

    // Stop the ping mechanism when the WebSocket is closed
    webSocket.value.onclose = function (event) {
        isConnected.value = false;
        console.log("WS Disconnected : " + JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));
        clearInterval(pingInterval);
    };
};
```

Comment: It's probably not a great idea to establish a websocket connection inside a random component that is rerendering, rerunning code, mounting/unmounting based on the app flow, etc.  Do this in some global state like a store and keep your websocket connection object and data there, outside of the flow of the rest of your app.  To your second question, websockets don't use tokens, [but you could append a token as a query param](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47625539/6225326)

Comment: @yoduh Thanks for your suggestion based on this, I have moved my connection logic to `composables/socketConnection.js`. This does not address the issue that I am facing. I am facing the issue with web socket opening the connection and immediately closes the connection. How to prevent the connection from closing immediately? I want to keep the connection open so that I can receive the message.