# Authenticating user via JWT before upgrading connection to a websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, jwt

I'm using Node v8.6.0 on the sever with [this library](https://github.com/websockets/ws). I will not be using Socket.io.

I would like a user to send (i.e. via a custom header) a JWT through a GET request that will then either get rejected (they aren't authorized) and prevent a websocket from being established, or, in the case they send a valid JWT, I want the GET request to be upgraded to a websocket.

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3001/upgrade', {
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'bearer jwtGoesHere',
        Upgrade: 'websocket',
        Connection: 'Upgrade',
        'Sec-WebSocket-Key': 'dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==',
        'Sec-WebSocket-Version': 13
    }
})
```

However, there is no way to send custom headers. If I try to send the required headers for upgrading to a websocket, I get an error: `Refused to set unsafe header`. Looking around the web, I see there are potentially 2 ways to send in some kind of information through when trying to establish a websocket connection: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361173/http-headers-in-websockets-client-api/41521871#41521871) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361173/http-headers-in-websockets-client-api/35890141#35890141). However, they seem kind of hacky to me or at least non-standard solutions (would it be okay to send a JWT through this way?).

Currently, this is what my code looks like on the server (with TypeScript):

```
    const webSockets: any = {};
    const webSocketServer: any = new WebSocket.Server({ noServer: true });
    server.on('upgrade', (request: any, socket: any, head: any) => {
        webSocketServer.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, (websocket: any) => {
            let userID: any;
            console.log('establishing websocket connection...');
            websocket.send('plz send ID');
            websocket.on('message', (message: any): any => {
                if (JSON.parse(message).userId) {
                    userID = JSON.parse(message).userId;
                    if (!webSockets[userID]) {
                        console.log('preparing websocket user...');
                        webSockets[userID] = websocket;
                    }
                    console.log(`connected: ${userID}`);
                }
            });

            websocket.on('close', (eventCode: any): any => {
                if (eventCode === 1006) {
                    console.log('Websocket disconnected abnormally');
                }
                if (eventCode === 1000) {
                    console.log('Websocket successfully closed normally');
                    delete webSockets[userID];
                    console.log(`deleted: ${userID}`);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

And on the client side I'm just using native WebSocket.