# Safari, Jetty : Websockets not working as authentication header is not sent

Tags: authentication, websocket, safari, jetty

We have a Spring-MVC application with websockets deployed on a Jetty server. We also have HashLoginService as shown below configured for jetty. When the application starts, we are able to access it with websockets functionality intact on FF, Chrome, Opera, IE but not on Safari. The only thing we get back is 401. After disabling the HashLoginService, websockets work fine. Is there some configuration in Jetty or somewhere required so that websockets work in Safari with authentication. Thank you.

```
Safari version : 11.0.3(desktop version)
Jetty - 9.4
```

jetty.xml :

```
  <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
               <Set name="name">Default Realm</Set>
               <Set name="config"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/realm.properties</Set>
            </New>
         </Arg>
      </Call>
```

web.xml from project:

```
<security-constraint>
            <web-resource-collection>
                <web-resource-name>username</web-resource-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            </web-resource-collection>
            <auth-constraint>
                <role-name>user-role</role-name>
            </auth-constraint>
        </security-constraint>

            <security-constraint>
                <web-resource-collection>
                    <web-resource-name>username</web-resource-name>
                    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
                </web-resource-collection>
                <auth-constraint>
                    <role-name>user-role</role-name>
                </auth-constraint>
            </security-constraint>

        <security-role>
            <role-name>user-role</role-name>
        </security-role>
```

Any idea what we can do? Thanks.

Comment: What version of Safari (and is this mobile safari or desktop/laptop safari)? and What version of Jetty?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt : I have also added it to the main post after ur comment. Thank you. Safari version : 11(desktop), Jetty : 9.4

Comment: Which websockets API are you using on Jetty? (Native WebSockets, or JSR356 WebSockets)?

Comment: @Joakim Erdfelt : I have enabled websockets module from start.ini by adding --module=websockets. I presume the default one is loaded, but how can I check.

Comment: That module makes both APIs available, its up to your webapp to choose one or the other (or in some rare cases both).   A stackdump while a websocket is active would tell you (are classes on package `org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356` present? then i'ts JSR356, otherwise it's native WebSocket)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt : sorry for the late reply. I am using native websocket implementation. Thank you.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt : Any ideas? thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Standard HTTP Authentication is apparently not supported on Safari and WebSockets.

See: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=80362

You can find some workarounds at a different stackoverflow answer.

[HTTP headers in Websockets client API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361173/http-headers-in-websockets-client-api)