# extraHeaders doesnt work in socket.io-client

Tags: node.js, socket.io, nwjs

Hi my code looks like this in nodejs, it works!

but when i try to use exactly same code in nwjs app, it doesn't! because as i sniff and see it thinks it runs under a web browser and it tries to use native functions of nwjs's chromium browser.

```
function connecttest(domain)
{
socket = require('socket.io-client')('https://ws.'+domain.replace('www.').replace('m.'),{
  forceNode:true,
  transports: ['websocket'],
  extraHeaders: {
      'Origin': 'https://www.'+domain.replace('www.').replace('m.')
  },
  transportOptions: {
    polling: {
      extraHeaders: {
        'Origin': 'https://www.'+domain.replace('www.').replace('m.')
      }
    }
  }
});
socket.on('connect',  function(socket){
    console.log("ok");
socket.emit('query', {"body":{"siteId":"9","source":1,"lang":"tr"},"action":"site.session","frontEndId":0,"token":null});
socket.on('response', function(data){
console.log(data);
});

});
}
```

[image: fiddler sniff]

as you see it can not set a right origin header

[image: but]

but it works under plain - nodejs script

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361173/http-headers-in-websockets-client-api/4361358#4361358

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps it is your `transports: ['websocket']`. Look here, at the [official documentation](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#With-extraHeaders):

> **With extraHeaders**
>
> This only works if `polling` transport is enabled
> (which is the default). Custom headers will not be appended when using
> `websocket` as the transport. This happens because the WebSocket
> handshake does not honor custom headers. (For background see the
> [WebSocket protocol RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-4))