# Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Connection' header is missing

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, websocket, socket.io

I'm completely new to Node, and even newer to Socket.io. I just got my first chat application online at spaiglas.com, which works despite an error in the developer console that is fairly straightforward...

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://example.com/...' failed`
`: Error during WebSocket handshake`
`: 'Connection' header is missing`

Here is a [**codepen**](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/gZrEdO) with all of my code. I've uploaded it to my hosting provider, which is using Passenger via cPanel on an Apache server in a Node 9.11.2 environment.

From what I've been reading, the 'Connection' headers can't be set using AJAX, which is supposedly a security risk, but instead is handled by the server? Is it possible to manually set this header?

I have noticed by looking at the headers that early on usually one of them always successfully switches/upgrades the protocol to WebSockets, but then the platform always seems to revert back to HTTPS/polling. In the case below, which I observed just now, there were actually 2 out of now 67 instances whereby it successfully switched to and used the WebSockets protocol.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have same problem. Did you solve your problem?

Comment: I installed nginx and solved my problem

Comment: @Hermes i dont think i ever solved the problem, but i didnt really bother trying to solve it since the long polling worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize socket.io before you start your HTTP server that is listening on port 80. In the docs it is...

```
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

And then later, you call `http.listen(3000, ...)`. This will start the socket.

On the client, your path is also incorrect. Websockets is a protocol `(ws://somedomain.com)`, just like HTTP. When you connect via `http://` that is a different protocol. I would either not pass it anything, or use namespaces which you can find in the socket.io documentation.

Socket.io reverts to long polling and sometimes doesn't even use websockets (which is partly why it is generally slower than libraries like ws on npm). Because of that, passing http:// into the io(...) on the client may not be wrong with their library, but I would remove it anyway and do my above suggestion.

Comment: yeah i have initialized all that stuff, which can be seen in the codepen. i think i simply need to change `socket = io.connect(...)` to `socket.io('url', { /* extraHeaders here*/ })`. im pretty sure that if i set the protocol to `ws`, then when websockets fails and it defaults to polling, it would break, wouldn't it?

Comment: the issue is that i need to figure out how to set a "connection" header

Comment: on the server, order matters. you need to do the order I said. In the code on the codepen you started the server listening before you started the socket.io server. you need change that, to create the server but not start it listening. and then start socket.io, and then start the server listening. on the client just delete the string you pass into it. It should be io.connect() not socket.io("url", ...}

Comment: I have had this issue before just like you. it is the order of your code on the server. your client is fine just delete the string in io.connect()

Comment: huh? how am i not initializing `socket.io` before initializing the server? `app = express()` initializes the server?

Comment: im brand new to all of this remember. also btw youre right i removed the protocol so its just `io.connect('example.com:80')` now

Comment: @Gihan Saranga Siriwardhana any idea?

Comment: If you just tried my solution it would've fixed it. The reason your code doesn't work is that app = express() does not start the server. it initializes it, but the server doesn't start until you call listen(). you need to make sure you call listen for the server AFTER you start your socket.io.