# AWS API Gateway Websocket - Chrome: Error during WebSocket handshake: Sent non-empty 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' header but no response was received

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, google-chrome, websocket, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to use AWS API Gateway's WebSocket functionality for communication with my Angular Application. As per enterprise requirement, It is required for me to secure my WebSocket endpoint with an OAuth token.

I have written an custom OAuth authorizer for validating OAuth token.

This Custom authorizer is working fine with my REST endpoints.

As per my understanding, browsers cannot support custom headers for WebSocket ([HTTP headers in Websockets client API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361173/http-headers-in-websockets-client-api)).

So as to bypass this limitation, I am using Sec-WebSocket-Protocol header for passing my OAuth token for authentication purpose.

(Query string based authentication might not work for me as, I would exceed the URL string limitations)

I have configured my API Gateway's configuration to accept Sec-WebSocket-Protocol as authentication header & everything seems to be working fine with WSCAT utility.

When I am integrating this endpoint with my Angular Client using RxJS (https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/webSocket/webSocket) this entire solution works fine in FireFox & Edge Browser, But Chrome throws an Handshake exception i.e.

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://xxxx.com/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Sent non-empty 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' header but no response was received`

**Request Headers:**

```
GET wss://xxxx.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxx.com
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Sec-WebSocket-Key: asdf
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: asdf
```

**Response Headers:**

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Connection: upgrade
Date: Tue, 11 Jun 2019 06:15:43 GMT
upgrade: websocket
sec-websocket-accept: asdf
sec-websocket-extensions: permessage-deflate
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 asdf
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: BOM51
X-Amz-Cf-Id: asdf
```

Comment: This seems strange, Switching Protocols should be the response of HTTP request not the wss request. HTTP request upgrade to ws.

Comment: Yes, I also felt the same way. But, strangely it feels like AWS Websocket is still not reliable enough for production ready deployments.

Comment: I've never seen a problem with aws websocket, I think it's something wrong with the test.

Comment: I guess this is definately a bug, in AWS WebSocket https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=883536&tstart=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a long-standing bug in AWS WebSocket API

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=883536&tstart=0

Comment: Link is not functional any more.

Answer (score 0):

Happy to report this has now been added to API-Gateway, so now you need to update your Lambda function to return the correct `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol` header: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/websocket-connect-route-subprotocol.html

Comment: It's possible to add this kind of return after and authorizer method on $connect ?