# Enable Authorization header in websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

We have to implement WebSocket connection with third-party WebSocket server. But they are using Authorization header for establishing a connection between WebSocket client and WebSocket server. But I could not find any solution to add Authorization header in WebSocket client during connection.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

This is my code I am using

```
var ws = new WebSocketClient();
var headers ={Authorization: 'token'}
ws.on('connectFailed', function(error) {
    console.log('Connect Error: ' + error.toString());
});

ws.on('connect', function(connection) {
    console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
});
ws.connect('wss://url', '',headers);
```

Response is like this

```
 Server responded with a non-101 status: 400 Bad Request
Response Headers Follow:
server: nginx/1.11.7
date: Thu, 11 Jul 2019 19:49:58 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 31
connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: What's the Web Socket client?  Your Node.js server?  And if so, what Web Socket client are you using?

Comment: We are using normal WebSocket client (WebSocket). We don't know about the server it is a third-party one

Comment: There isn't some "normal" WebSocket client, there are a handful commonly used.  You should be able to look at your code and package.json and figure out which it is.  Is it this?  https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket

Comment: yes it is the one

Comment: Right in the documentation is an example for passing additional headers:  https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node/blob/6e62787df0ccc9a34b12c134686aef07716849f3/docs/WebSocketClient.md#connectrequesturl-requestedprotocols-origin-headers-requestoptions

Comment: I tried but I got 400 bad request error
Is any way see the request header values in this library

Comment: Why don't you post your code then?  If you've already been able to add this header, then you already know how to do it, which is what your question is asking.  It's really frustrating to try to help someone without the extra context.  That's why on Stack Overflow we ask for examples and ask you to better explain what you've tried.

Comment: @Brad sorry for my mistake. I was not sure I am in right way. That's why asked like this. Sorry again.
Updated the question with my code and response

Comment: It doesn't look like `headers` are actually used.

Comment: It was actually I removed the header's to whether what happening when its is not there
Updated the question with using headers

Comment: Ok, and did you see this part of the documentation?  "origin must be specified if you want to pass headers, and both origin and headers must be specified if you want to pass requestOptions. The origin and headers parameters may be passed as null."  You're not passing an origin.

Comment: Can we put * as origin?

Comment: That's up to the server you're connecting to.

Comment: ok, Do we have any option to see the request header of request?

Comment: Thanks, @Brad, I could able to connect to that server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP headers in Websockets client API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361173/http-headers-in-websockets-client-api)