# WebSockets and HTTP headers

Tags: javascript, go, browser, websocket, http-headers

I am trying to figure out how to add a header with an authorization token to a WebSocket connection, after it has been established. Basically, to use a cookie in order to validate each message in the connection.

There is a great discussion at [HTTP headers in Websockets client API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361173/http-headers-in-websockets-client-api) already, yet it did not really help me.

One of the the suggestions there was to do:

```
document.cookie = 'X-Authorization=' + token + '; path=/';
```

Unfortunately, it did not help me.

```
func handler(ws *websocket.Conn, h *Hub) {
    go h.run()
    h.addClientChan <- ws
    for {
        config := ws.Config()
        fmt.Println("Headers length:", len(config.Header))
        ...
```

Shows a map with 0 elements before and after I add the cookie.

Is it possible to alter WebSocket connection headers, after the connection has been established?

Do I even need to add an authorization token to a WebSocket connection, provided I authenticate each time, or is it only useful to re-establish a connection and just a useless check after the fact?

Comment: Could you please show full code of golang server? Perhaps you're fetching headers in the wrong way.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look. Not positive that more code here will help, but I added a couple more lines. Since everything else is running, assuming that `ws` is valid. Right? I am able to receive messages from this WebSocket - `ws` a few lines further down.

Comment: Please add more relevant code, it still unclear which library you're using, how all setuped and all other stuff.

Comment: I am using `"golang.org/x/net/websocket"`, The thing is setup with `http.NewServeMux()` and `mux.Handle()`. Is it possible to add headers to a WebSocket connection after it has been established?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to alter WebSocket connection headers, after the
>   connection has been established?

You can't set a cookie upon receipt of a WebSocket message. Once the WebSocket connection has been established, it's an open TCP socket and the protocol is no longer http, thus there is no built-in way to exchange cookies.

You can use authorizathion on the first http request, where both sides establish protocol for exchange data.

Comment: This is what I thought. Thank you