# Rxjs Websocket : how to add headers

Tags: javascript, angular, websocket, rxjs

I'm using websocket in my Angular app using rxjs.

I'm instanciating it like this : i want to add some headers :

```
myheader : "abcde"
```

**how my i do it ?**

here is my code:

```
import { BehaviorSubject, of, Subscription, Subject, Observable, NextObserver } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class WebsocketService  {

  openConnection() {
    this.close();
    const url = 'wss://echo.websocket.org';
    this.connection$ = webSocket({
      url, 
      openObserver: this.openObserver,
      closeObserver: this.closeObserver,
    });
    this.getmsg();

  }
}
```

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: I'm using `@stomp/ng2-stompjs` to help me with websocket connections. the `rxStompService` has a `configure` which allows for `connectHeaders`. I don't think the ordinary WebSocket API allows for headers. You could pass some query parameters to the url though... `wss://echo.websocket.org?firstvar=test`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP headers in Websockets client API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361173/http-headers-in-websockets-client-api)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to pass additional headers when creating a `WebSocket`, neither with RxJS nor with plain JavaScript / DOM API.

You can use **Query Params** or **Cookies** to provide additional details to your server.