# Is is possible to add a request header to an RxJs Websocket?

Tags: javascript, angular, websocket, rxjs

I'm looking to create a basic Websocket connection from my angular application to a server. Per RxJs documentation, the 'websocket' method is a wrapper around the WebSocket object provided by the browser:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { webSocket } from 'rxjs/webSocket';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class WebSocketService {

  connect(url: string) {
    return webSocket(url);
  }
}
```

While the examples are pretty straight forward, what I find surprising is the lack of documentation around a scenario where the the browser would need to send data as part of a request header (ie: an auth token) for the server to satisfy the request. Is this supported by JavaScript WebSockets?

I've seen a [workaround](https://yeti.co/blog/token-based-header-authentication-for-websockets-behind-nodejs/) where the websocket url would add the token as a query parameter (see image below), but that is a security vulnerability that should be avoided. Any suggestions or references would help!

[image]

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361173/http-headers-in-websockets-client-api

Answer (score 1):

No.

The underlying API does not support any additional parameters (other than URL and protocols).

For more detail check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361173/http-headers-in-websockets-client-api)

One possible solution that is not explained in the linked answer is that you could set a cookie from the server in a prior request. That cookie should then be re-sent to the server when you open the WebSocket. For that to work, make sure to enable [withCredentials](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#withCredentials) in your HttpService

Comment: I'm the lead author of RxJS, and this is the correct answer. The `WebSocket` API doesn't support it.