# Spoofing Origin header in Node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, spoofing

I'm working on a bot and I keep getting a 403 error when trying to connect to the server through ws. From what I've found online the problem seems to be the Origin header. Is there any way I can spoof the Origin header in **node.js** with socket.io? **(NOT BROWSER)**

Comment: Did you check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4361358/1043231

Comment: I don't see how I can use that to change my origin header. Sorry, I'm kinda new to this.

Comment: You need to share some code you tired so we can help you