# JWT (Authorization header) gets removed by Nginx when forwarding to websocket endpoint. HTTP everything works

Tags: http, nginx, websocket, jwt, authorization

I am using Nginx as reverse proxy with the following configuration file.

[image]

There is one endpoint at 127.0.0.1:8081 which creates a websocket connection. Almost every endpoint is secured by a JWT authorization.

When I am sending requests to the HTTP endpoints everything works fine and the `Authorization` header gets forwarded to my backend application. It just does not work when requesting the websocket endpoint. The `Authorization` Header is null then so it gets kinda cut from Nginx or something like that. When I remove the required Authorization in my backend application the websocket connection and the http endpoint both work perfectly fine. It's just the `Authorization` Header when calling the `wss://domain/chat`.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: I don't think you can send headers through a websocket. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4361358/1623249