# How to include a Bearer Token when opening a Ktor Client WebSocket?

Tags: ktor, ktor-client

I am trying to open a WebSocket (WSS) connection using the Ktor Client (v2.3.0), somewhat like this:

```kotlin
suspend fun main() {
    val client = HttpClient() {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json()
        }
        install(WebSockets) {
            pingInterval = 300_000
        }
        defaultRequest {
            url(window.location.origin)
        }
    }

    client.wss(
        request = {
            url.takeFrom("wss://localhost:8000/ws/test")
            header("Authorization", "Bearer THISTOKENISINVALID00")
        },
        block = {
            close(CloseReason(CloseReason.Codes.NORMAL, ""))
        }
    )
}
```

However, when I observe the network in my browser, **the *Authorization* header is missing** on the corresponding request. (As such, it gets denied by my backend.)

How can I include the header properly?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is not achievable in JavaScript, because you cannot add custom headers to websocket requests. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4361358/14612693).