# How to add authorization headers to HTTP upgrade messages when using Subscriptions over websockets in a NODEJS Application?

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, apollo-client, graphql-ws

I have a NODE application that also acts as a GraphQL client.
I need to fetch the data from a GraphQL server using SUBSCRIPTION requests.

The GraphQL server validates the incoming HTTP upgrade message during the handshake to establish the WebSocket connection. The validation is done by looking at the `Cookie` header for a token.

I am using the [graphql-ws](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/ws/get-started) library. The library does allow me to create a subscription client, but I haven't been successful in adding the authorization headers to the outgoing HTTP upgrade messages.

Here is my code:

```
import { createClient } from 'graphql-ws';
    
const sClient = createClient({
        url: graphqlWsServer,
        webSocketImpl: WebSocket
      });

      (async () => {
        try {
            const subscription = sClient.iterate({
                query: query
              });
             
              for await (const event of subscription) {
                console.log(event);
             
                //Complete a running subscription by breaking the iterator loop
                break;
              }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("ERROR OCCURRED!!");
            console.log(err);
        }
        
      })();
```

The above code results in `403`.
How to add the authorization headers to the outgoing HTTP upgrade messages before socket connection is established. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close!  You need to extend `WebSocket` when passing a custom implementation to webSocketImpl.

The [documentation for graphql-ws has an example](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/ws/recipes#client-usage-in-node-with-custom-headers-not-possible-in-browsers) of implementing a custom client with headers and using it with createClient.

Applying this to your use case would be something like:

```js
const WebSocket = require('ws');
import { createClient } from 'graphql-ws';

class WebSocketWithHeaders extends WebSocket {
  constructor(address, protocols) {
    super(address, protocols, {
      headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'graphql-ws client',
        'Authorization': '<token>',
        // or use a cookie like this
        //'Cookie': 'JWT=<token>'
      },
    });
  }
}

const sClient = createClient({
        url: graphqlWsServer,
        webSocketImpl: WebSocketWithHeaders
      });

      (async () => {
        try {
            const subscription = sClient.iterate({
                query: query
              });
             
              for await (const event of subscription) {
                console.log(event);
             
                //Complete a running subscription by breaking the iterator loop
                break;
              }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("ERROR OCCURRED!!");
            console.log(err);
        }
        
      })();
```

edit: forgot to mention that this only works outside of the browser.  [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361173/http-headers-in-websockets-client-api/4361358#4361358) for details.

Comment: Thank you. This is the exact thing that I needed. It worked like a charm.