# Send data to server using jQuery $.ajax Post method

Tags: jquery, post

I use jQuery Ajax to send data to server. I set post type as POST but data always get send using GET method. How to send data using Post method?

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",        
        dataType: 'jsonp',            
        url: 'http://do.convertapi.com/Web2Image/json/',
        data: {
            'CUrl':$('#txtUrl').val(),
            'OutputFormat':'png',
            'PageWidth':600,
            'ApiKey':apiKey
        },
        jsonp: "callback",
        success: function (data) {               
        if (data.Result)
        {                
            $('#imgSnapShot').attr('src','data:image/png;base64,'+data.File); 
            $('#dvStatus').text("Converted successfully!");
        }
        else {
            $('#dvStatus').text("Error: " + data.Error);
        }             
        },
        });
```

As Graham Clark posted, jsonp Ajax requests are always posted as GET. If I remove jsonp option I get another problem, cross domain posting error. Is there any solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1):

As it a 5 year old question but still if some one finds it useful ..
More recently browsers have implemented a technology called Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), that allows Ajax requests to different domains.
so have to use cors instead of jsonp

Answer (score 0):

I believe `jsonp` is always sent with a GET request. If you need POST then use `json`. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508198/how-to-use-type-post-in-jsonp-ajax-call) for details.

Comment: I use jsonp to overcome cross domain posting problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send cross-domain requests via JSONP - it doesn't use XMLHttpRequest. See here for more information:

http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/e7eb4a23eef342fb?pli=1