# send POST request with angularJS despite same-origin policy

Tags: ajax, post, angularjs, same-origin-policy

Is there a way to send a POST request using AngularJS despite the same-origin policy?
I don't need to get the response from the request, I just need to send the request.
Just like creating a form and sending it to another server.

Thanks

Comment: what happened when you tried it?

Comment: It says that I don't have the same origin

Comment: same origin security restrictions are monitored by the browser itself regardless of whatever javascript framework you use...use a proxy on your domain to make post to other domain

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSONP to send a request to another domain, however you can't use POST, it would have to be a GET request. Can you serialize your form values and send using GET?

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http#jsonp

[How to use type: "POST" in jsonp ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508198/how-to-use-type-post-in-jsonp-ajax-call)

Keep in mind that if you do use GET, you are limited with how much data you send, since URLs usually can't be over ~2000 characters.