# Multiple Form Submits to Cross Domain Sites

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, jsonp

I have an application where I am required to perform multiple form submits to external sites. I want the form submits to open new tabs. 
What I do is I create a form element using javascript, and then I just do a `form.submit()`. I am aware that only **one** will make it through.

I am looking for work arounds. One way is using jsonp:

I have something like this so far

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: path, 
    type: "POST", 
    async: "false",
    contentType: 'application/x-javascript',
    data: $('this').serializeArray(),
    success: function (html) {
        if (data != "") {     
                var link = html;
                window.open(link,'', ''); //open's link in newly opened tab!
            }
      },
      failure: function (html) {
        alert(html);
      }
    });
        return false; 
    });
```

However even I do specified the `type` to be `post`, I see in the chrome developer tools that I have an actual get being sent. I am guessing that is because of window.open.

Can somebody suggest techniques to achieve this/

Thank you

Comment: *"However even I do specified the type to be post, I see in the chrome developer tools that I have an actual get being sent. I am guessing that is because of window.open."* No, it's because [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) is **inherently** a `GET` operation.

Comment: For additional explanation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508198/how-to-use-type-post-in-jsonp-ajax-call

Comment: Whoever marked this as a duplicate and guided me to a "How to use type: “POST” in jsonp ajax call" - please be aware that my question is not how to use POST with jsonp ajax calls. My question is to perform Multiple Form Submits to Cross Domain Sites ... If there is a question that has this answered (there is none), then you can mark this as complete.

Comment: I am guessing the best approach would be to have a proxy written in php, which receives the post and then posts it forward.

Answer (score 1):

> I am required to perform multiple form submits to external sites. I want the form submits to open new tabs. What I do is I create a form element using javascript, and then I just do a form.submit().

If you set the [`target` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-target) of the form element to `"_blank"` in the HTML, and set the [`action` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-action) of the form element instance to each of the external URLs in a loop (e.g., set the URL, call `submit`; set the next URL, call `submit`), you should be able to submit the form multiple times. (You'll probably have to do this within the handling of a user-generated event, and even then I wouldn't be absolutely sure a browser wouldn't — and shouldn't — block multiple new tabs sprouting up.)

But I would **strongly** push back on the original requirement, unless it's *absolutely clear* to the end user what you're going to be doing when they click that button or whatever.

Comment: Mr Crowder, this results with only one of those 4 form submits being submitted. I tried this approach before posting here.

Comment: @imparator: Gosh, if only you'd **mentioned that** in your question. (Four, eh? With what browser?)

Comment: can't that implied by *"I am required to perform multiple form submits to external sites"*?

Comment: With Chrome ... it works with Firefox

Comment: And four is just an example ... The whole point is about doing <strong>multiple</strong>

Comment: @KevinB: No, "I am required" can't be taken to mean "I have tried X and it hasn't worked."