# Want to POST Text to Tumblr

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tumblr

I am Able to Perform the GET Method for Tumblr Blog, 
But Whenever I try to Perform the POST Method for Tumblr then At that time I get an Error as::

```
({"meta":{"status":401,"msg":"Not Authorized"},"response":[]});
```

I am using the Following code for Ajax Post::

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/firstblgpsa.tumblr.com/post',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {
        api_key: "*key here*",
        type: 'text',
        title: 'First_Post',
        body:'This is My First Post to Tumblr.'
    },
    success:function(){
        alert("Blog Posted Successfully!!");
    }
})
```

Comment: `jsonp` doesn't support method POST. To be more precise, you can't use  method other than GET in cross-domain ajax. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508198/how-to-use-type-post-in-jsonp-ajax-call

Comment: But what should I do If I want to Post Some text into My Tumblr Blog.

Comment: I don't think you want others to start using your key and upload stuff on your behalf, removed your key.

Answer (score 2):

On the client side (in the browser) you are allowed from default to use only GET requests. This is the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). There are some tricks to go around this but I would not recommend doing that.

It's not even possible with JSONP see more details in [q: How to use type: “POST” in jsonp ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508198/how-to-use-type-post-in-jsonp-ajax-call) question

**What you should do:**
The correct way of doing things like this is to send the request to your domains server (backend) and do the request against tumblr from your backend server directly with `php` or `ruby` or w/e you got there.

Comment: But If I am not Using that DataType in My AJAX POST method then also I am not able to Create a New Blog on Tumblr