# How do I retrieve the responseText of a jquery.ajax error?

Tags: jquery

The code goes like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://server.com/rest",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success:function(d, t, x) {
        console.log(d);
    },
    error:function(x, t, e) {
        console.log(x.responseText);
    }
});
```

Firebug shows that I am receiving a response but the code above only logs "undefined". Firebug also shows that the http status code is 200. Can anybody tell me how to retrieve the response?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035557/jsonp-request-error-handling

Comment: jqXHR.responseText gives me "undefined"

Comment: See link posted by @AnthonyGarcia

Comment: You can't get the responseText in the error because there is no reponseText in an error condition.

Comment: How does firebug retrieve the response then? -- just curious

Answer (score 1):

if you are using jsonp. your server should bind the response to a callback function.
Example

**server response**

```
myFunction(someresponsehere)
```

**client side**

```
function myFunction(response)
{
  //you will get the response from server here "response"
  }
```

Comment: I know but in this case I don't control the server. The server only returns the data without the callback so the callback is never called.  I can't use a non-jsonp call because I get an "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error. The only way I get data back is if I use jsonp.

Comment: @ferdtomale than you are out of luck.