# Ajax request to server, error function is not calling

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova

i am sending ajax request to server to get the database. But if i enter incorrect data (which is to be sent over server) nothing is happening, error function is not working, all i am doing is to verify credentials from the server

here is my code

```
$.ajax
    ({
        url: "URL",
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "jsonp",

        data: {type: 'login', id: C_id},
        ContentType: "application/json",

        success: function(res) 
        {

            var simpleJson = JSON.parse(res);

            myDB.transaction(function (txe1) 
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < simpleJson.User.length; i++) 
                {
                    var Cli_id= simpleJson.User[i].id;
                    myDB.transaction(function (txe) 
                    {
                        txe.executeSql('CREATE TABLE Client_data(Mobile integer , C_id integer, U_id integer , name text , ip integer )');
                    }); 


                    myDB.transaction(function (txe1) 
                    {

                        var data_ins = 'INSERT INTO Client_data (Mobile,C_id,U_id) VALUES (?,?,?)';
                        txe1.executeSql(data_ins, [p,C_id,U_id]
                        ,function(tx, result)
                        {
                            navigator.notification.alert('Inserted' ,  onSignup, 'Info', 'ok'); 

                        },
                        function(error)
                        {
                            navigator.notification.alert('Already Registered'); 
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        },
    });
});
```

my PHP code

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');
$conn = mysql_connect("***", "***", "****");
if (!$conn) 
{
    echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db("ekspeser_pro")) 
{
    echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if(isset($_GET['type']))
{
    if($_GET['type'] == "login")
    {
        $id=$_GET['id'];    
        $sql = "SELECT  * from client_master WHERE id='$id'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);                            
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($num_rows!=0)
        {
            while($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            {
                $recipes[]=$myrow;
            }

            $output = json_encode(array('User' => $recipes));
            echo $output;

        }
        else
        {
             print "invalid key";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print "invalid login";
    }   
}

    else
    {
        echo "invalid";
    }

mysql_close();


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the **error** callback to perform some operation when the request fails. This is how you can implement request failure callback.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/save/author",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  data: { name: "John", age: "35" },
  success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
    alert("request succeed");
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, status, err) {
    alert("request failed");
  }
})
```

as per this example, we are just showing an alert with text `request failed`. You can implement it accordingly as per your requirement.

Comment: i have tried it..but its not working cuz i am working on cross doamin and jquery API documentation says "error handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests."

Comment: You might want to have a look at @Tommi Gustafsson's http://stackoverflow.com/a/22831262/2911348

Comment: @prateek what's the error code you are getting? Some error code like 401 dont invoke error callback

Answer (score 0):

If i get you correct,you want to validate the data passed to your url, if i am getting you correct you want to handle,please refer below:

**Ajax error function will only be called if the request fails, see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/**

So if you return any response from your PHP server/API, the error function won't be triggered as **The "error" setting of the ajax method is fired when the calls fails in the sending process. Errors like "timeout", "404", etc...**

However, you can return a key from your PHP code as below to handle success and error in your ajax code:

```
$data['error'] = $success ? 0:1;// If success than set error to 0 else 1;
```

and in AJAX success you can handle it as :

```
success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
    if(data.error)
      //do something
    else
      //do something else
}
```

Let me know if any queries

**------EDIT------------------**

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');
$conn = mysql_connect("***", "***", "****");
if (!$conn) 
{
    echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db("ekspeser_pro")) 
{
    echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if(isset($_GET['type']))
{
    if($_GET['type'] == "login")
    {
        $id=$_GET['id'];    
        $sql = "SELECT  * from client_master WHERE id='$id'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);                            
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        $is_error=0;
        if($num_rows!=0)
        {
            while($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            {
                $recipes[]=$myrow;
            }

            $output = json_encode(array('User' => $recipes,'is_error'=>$is_error));
            echo $output;

        }
        else
        {
             $is_error=1;
             $error_message = "Invalid Key";
             $output = json_encode(array('is_error'=>$is_error,'error_message'=>$error_message));
             echo $output;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $is_error=1;
        $error_message = "Invalid Login";
        $output = json_encode(array('is_error'=>$is_error,'error_message'=>$error_message));
        echo $output;
    }   
}

    else
    {
        $is_error=1;
        $error_message = "Invalid";
        $output = json_encode(array('is_error'=>$is_error,'error_message'=>$error_message));
        echo $output;
    }

mysql_close();


?>
```

In AJAX Code access it like this :

```
Check for following in success
if(simpleJson.is_error!=1)
   //do your processing
else
   alert(simpleJson.error_message);
```

Let me know if anything unclear

Comment: got error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'is_error' of undefined"

Comment: can you console.log the `res` to check if you are getting correct response

Comment: so you just need to check if is_error is set to 1
If anything unclear share your updated code

Comment: Above you shown us the log message that has is_error set,so to help you further i need to see what you have done in ajax,so post that code