# Getting "$.jsonp is not a function" error

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I am getting `$.jsonp is not a function` error. Have included js from this link: http://cloud.github.com/downloads/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp/jquery.jsonp-2.4.0.js

Any thing else needs to be included. Checking in firefox 25.0v.

Code used is:

```
$.jsonp({
  "url": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/123456?callback=?",
  "data": {
      "alt": "json-in-script"
  },
  "success": function(userProfile) {
      alert("Could not find user ");
  },
  "error": function(d,msg) {
      alert("Could not find user ");
  }
});
```

This was sample code given at site:
https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp/blob/master/doc/TipsAndTricks.md

Comment: Sorry to ask stupid questions, but you're including jQuery right?

Comment: yes I have included jquery.jsonp-2.4.0.js , it can be seen by checking the page source.

Comment: I mean the jQuery library itself.

Comment: yes included jquery-1.4.3.min.js,jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not strict with

> $.jsonp();

then  You can use jsonp ajax request like below as well:

```
$.ajax({
dataType: "jsonp",
url: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/123456?callback=?",
"data": {
  "alt": "json-in-script"
 },
 "success": function(userProfile) {
  alert("Could not find user ");
 },
  "error": function(d,msg) {
  alert("Could not find user ");
 }
```

> dataType: "jsonp"

will be useful for your jsonp call.

Comment: before I was using $.ajax,but it does not do proper error handling hence was not able to handle exceptions like on session timeout etc.
check 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035557/jsonp-request-error-handling

Comment: You can also use jQuery ajax Timeout  for handling timeout

Comment: yes.but we need to handle for status 12029,0,500 error also