# Error handling for Remote Autocomplete is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this jquery autocomplete code.Everything works fine data is loaded etc.Success is working.But when i have error...error handling is not working in below code.

```
 $("#autocomplete").on("filterablebeforefilter", function (e, data) {

      if (value && value.length > 0) {
        //$ul.listview("refresh");
             $('.ui-responsive-panel').enhanceWithin();
             $.ajax({
                       type: "GET",
                       url: "http://domain.com/food.php",
                       dataType: "jsonp",
                       crossDomain: true,
                       data: $(this).serialize(),
                       success: function (data) {
                            alert("success");
                       },
                       error: function () {
                             alert("an error occurred!");
                       },
                       beforeSend: function () {
                            // This callback function will trigger before data is sent
                       },
                       complete: function () {
                            setTimeout(function () {}, 1);
                       }
                     })
                     .then(function (response) {
                             $.each(response, function (i, val) {
                                 //do something with data
                             });
                         }
                 });
```

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery `Deferred` methods like `$.ajax().done().fail()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the jQuery doc states for [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) error handler functions:

> **Note**: *This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests.*

It is related to the technique of JSONP where the actual request is injected as a `<script>` tag. So a standard jqXHR object including an ajax error event isn't available. There's some plugin as workaround available. This plugin and solutions for dealing with network timeouts are discussed e.g. in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035557/jsonp-request-error-handling) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002367/jquery-ajax-jsonp-ignores-a-timeout-and-doesnt-fire-the-error-event?rq=1) stackoverflow questions.

Comment: Just same domain or also switching dataType? (=> jsonp is the problem!).

Comment: so what should be there instead of jsonp ? for same domain ?

Comment: "json" for example? But you probably have reasons for choosing "jsonp"!(?) Please first understand what the difference between json and jsonp is - then re-read my answer. It would exceed the comments' area purpose discussing this here.

Comment: yea thanks i read it..converting jsonp to json is working fine now :)

Comment: Happy to hear that :). Well, if you nevertheless need cross-domain resource access with jsonp, you should have a look on the other answers i referred to.

Answer (score 0):

Try handling the error in the `then` (or use `done()` and `fail()` )

```
  $.ajax({
           //... code omitted ...
                 })
                 .then(
                     function (response) {
                         $.each(response, function (i, val) {
                             //do something with data
                         });
                     },
                     function (error) {
                         //do something with error
                     }
             });
```