# How to log errors for the AJAX API calls which are cross domain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have tried the functionality of error logging  with the ajaxError.

Its working perfectly well but it does not work with cross domain.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).ajaxError(function(event,request,settings){
      console.log('error');
});
});
```

Is there a way to log errors for the AJAX API calls for cross domain(https) , in similar way as above ?

Comment: Maybe this post is helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035557/jsonp-request-error-handling/19185826#19185826

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery documentation] mentioned that `ajaxError` does not work with cross-domain scripts.

I would rather use `jqXHR.fail()` to do error handling per ajax call, unless you have too many APIs to call.

```
$.get('https://another.domain.com/api/data.json', function() {
    console.log('success');
}).fail(function() {
    console.log('error');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to make a monitoring javascript  which  monitors my frontend ajax calls. If any error occurs it gets logged in file. Is it feasible to use such jqXHR.fail() for monitoring purpose ?

Comment: it depends on how many ajax calls you have... say, if you have only a few ajax calls you can simply add `.fail()` to all your ajax calls and call a common error logging function inside it...otherwise if you have thousands of ajax calls (which is not likely the case) you have to fix too much code which is difficult from the perspective of source code management.