# jquery ajax response error not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax Call to an API which will return correctly (200) when the URL and the parameters are fine. Now I am trying to force an error with a bad request. Console will inform me about error code 400 but never seems to get into the error method. Instead it gets stuck in some jquery line and never returns.

```
 fetch: function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
        var apiUrl = this.applyFilter(filters);
        var self = this;

        this.log('fetch', apiUrl, currentSearchMode);

        $.ajax({
            url: apiUrl,
            type: 'GET',
            cache: (debug) ? true: false,
            processData: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            scriptCharset: 'UTF-8',
            jsonp: 'callback',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data, statusText, jqXHR) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                // if(jqXHR.status == 400){
                //     console.log('there is an error');
                // }
                self.log('fetch::success', data);
                if (typeof data.error !== 'undefined') {
                    showNoResultError = true;
                    var appData = lastValidResult[currentSearchMode];
                } else {
                    showNoResultError = false;
                    var appData = self.normalize[currentSearchMode](self, data);
                    lastValidResult[currentSearchMode] = appData;
                }
                if (typeof successCallback === 'function')
                    successCallback(appData);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //do sth here

                // if(jqXHR.status&&jqXHR.status==400){
                //     alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                // }else{
                //     alert("Something went wrong");
                // }
                // console.log('works now');
                // self.log('fetch::error', textStatus, errorThrown);
                // if (typeof errorCallback === 'function')
                //     errorCallback.apply(this, arguments);
            },
            complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log('complete');
            }
        });
    },
```

So the image shows where it gets stuck. I can only catch complete and success functions but when there a 400 response there is nothing happening. Tried anything, also done(), fail() since I assumed there might be a problem with deprecated behavior. But same problem there. Can anybody help, please?

Comment: Is the URL valid? Can you show your browser console?

Comment: Your server should support the type of request which is being sent.

Comment: The URL is valid but intentionally called using wrong parameters to provoke a 400 status code which is returned but will not be handled by my error code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
fetch: function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
        var apiUrl = this.applyFilter(filters);
        var self = this;

        this.log('fetch', apiUrl, currentSearchMode);

        $.ajax({
            url: apiUrl,
            type: 'GET',
            cache: (debug) ? true: false,
            processData: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            scriptCharset: 'UTF-8',
            jsonp: 'callback',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data, statusText, jqXHR) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                // if(jqXHR.status == 400){
                //     console.log('there is an error');
                // }
                self.log('fetch::success', data);
                if (typeof data.error !== 'undefined') {
                    showNoResultError = true;
                    var appData = lastValidResult[currentSearchMode];
                } else {
                    showNoResultError = false;
                    var appData = self.normalize[currentSearchMode](self, data);
                    lastValidResult[currentSearchMode] = appData;
                }
                if (typeof successCallback === 'function')
                    successCallback(appData);
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data.responseText);
            },
            complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log('complete');
            }
        });
    },
```

then, show me what's in your console

Comment: Thx. I tried your code but got the same result as before. The hint from @karthick seems to be reason for this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Error callback will not be fired for crossdomain requests or for jsonp requests.

search for the below in the reference link.

**Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests.**

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

You can look at this answer for how to handle errors for jsonp requests

[JSONP request error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035557/jsonp-request-error-handling)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This seems to be the problem.