# JSONP get status reponse

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use an ajax request to fetch data from an api. Due to CORS issues, I have to request JSONP as dataType. Now I want to provide some information about validation errors to the users, which comes from the endpoint.

```
$.ajax({
        url: patBaseUrl,
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: { apikey:  patBaseToken, query: query},
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        contentType: "application/javascript",
        xhrFields: {
          withCredentials: true
      },
        success: function(response) {
            addAlert('success', '<b>Success!</b> Query was sent successfully!');
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            addAlert('warning', '<b>Warning!</b> Something went wrong: ' + xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.statusText);
            console.log(xhr.status, xhr.statusText);
        }
```

In the console I get for e.g. `GET.... 404 Missing-Query` How do I get the text `Missing-Query`?

Comment: Did you check the network response in the developer tools?

Comment: I think you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035557/jsonp-request-error-handling

Comment: With JSONP you are not going to get the error message.