# Cross Origin ajax "POST" request failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, cors

I have a webservice(REST) running on localhost:8080, to call the webservice I use this jquery code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/user/register",
        data: '{"name": "' + name + '","email": "' + email + '","password": "' + password + '"}',
         beforeSend: function(x) {
              if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
               x.overrideMimeType(jsonMimeType);
              }
             },
        dataType:"jsonp",
        Accept : "application/json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: registerUser_success_callback,
        error: registerUser_error_callback
    });
```

When I try to call this javascript from the same domain(i.e. localhost:8080), it work just like a charm!. Here is the screen shot of the same:
[image]

But when I try to access the same from a different domain(i.e localhost:80), it fails, and surprisingly instead of a POST, it sends out a GET and I also get a log in my server's log file, saying that the GET method not supported for REST resource. Here is the screen of the same:
[image]

From what I have read on internet(especially [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2327-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-ajax-requests-between-jquery-and-node-js.htm), great article!), cross domain request should first send out an OPTIONS request(which is cached for later usage.) What is going wrong in my case?

I have tried calling the rest service with same parameters using FireFox's plugin RESTClient, I was able call the rest service(POST method) successfully, so this mostly is the issue with ajax part.

Help me resolve this cors hell! and do lemme know if I need to share any more details on this.

PS: After @A. Wolff Suggested, I changed the data tyoe from jsonp to json, now my browser sends out OPTIONS, but after that it doesn't send the actual POST request!!!

Comment: You cannot use POST method with jsonp due to nature of jsonp

Comment: Thanks @A.Wolff for quick response! can you explain that in a bit more detail? or an weblinks?

Comment: You can see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508198/how-to-use-type-post-in-jsonp-ajax-call   Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks! just curious, why would it work if the request is coming from the same domain? @A.Wolff

Comment: It shouldn't. Again, a POST method is unable to create a script tag client side which is the way jsonp works. But using CORS, you shouldn't have to use jsonp, try using json instead

Comment: @A.Wolff : i just edited the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, some more digging and I found the solution to this!

After the change A. Wolff suggested, browser was sending out an OPTIONS request and was receiving a 200 response, but after that actual POST request was not being sent to the server.

Problem was, if you send any specific headers, "Content-Type" in my case, server has to add that header in "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" field of the response(response of OPTIONS request). I changed my server side code to populate that field in the response header, and VOILA!

Hope this will be helpful to others, too!

Happy Coding.

Comment: Check out the W3C spec on [**Cross-Origin Resource Sharing**](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) as well.