# 405 error while form submission even though using POST request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am submitting my form data in JSON format to a third-party server using an AJAX call, but I'm getting a **405 error** (method not allowed). Could you please help?

My form looks like this:

```
<form name="freeTrial" id="testForm" role="form" >
------------
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit" id="submitButton"/>
</form>
```

And the script I am using is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("page load");
    $("#submitButton").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        alert("inside function");
        var MyForm = $("#testForm").serializeJSON();
        alert("MyForm "+JSON.stringify(MyForm));
        jQuery.ajax({
            url : "https://myServerURl/accounts",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data : MyForm,
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                console.log("failure");
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: But this error tells you everything that you need to know. Have you got defined in your controllers request mapping /accounts for POST request? And can you debug, what URL you are calling on submit button click?

Comment: Secondly, you should add this event on form submit, not on button click.

Comment: jsonp doesn't support POST (as it is implemented by making a GET request using a `script` tag) - did you mean `dataType: 'json'`?

Comment: @Sean: jsonp required for CORS request and json for same domain.

Comment: Maybe these links could help [http://stackoverflow.com/q/2558977/2456894](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2558977/2456894) , [http://stackoverflow.com/q/3506208/2456894](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3506208/2456894)

Comment: @Vaibhav - JSON CORS requests works just fine, as long as you are not using IE 8 / 9 - jQuery checks the target url's domain and [does the right thing if it doesn't match the requested one](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/e0673dfedb9ad07d8e68f28a54453b975c412c33/src/ajax.js#L507-L525).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `jsonp` with POST, it just doesn't work.
If this link targets same application you are calling from - use json data type.

If not, you must on target Server enable (by applying specific heards) Cross Domain requests. This can be done only inside `https://myServerURl` server. Than you could use simply `json` data type, instead of `jsonp`.

Related post:
[How to use type: "POST" in jsonp ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508198/how-to-use-type-post-in-jsonp-ajax-call)

Comment: thnx.. i get the point.. actually its a third part server url we are posting to..will have to enable it on server...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually attempting to make a Cross-domain (CORS) request, not an ordinary POST. Modern browsers allows only Ajax calls to services in the same domain as the HTML page.

**How to solve it?**

The simplest way is to enable CORS (enable the necessary headers) on the server.

If you don't have server-side access to it, you can mirror the web service from somewhere else, and then enable CORS there.

Comment: we have to post the data to a third party server...used jsonp for cross domain request..didnt know post wont work here....