# POST gets converted to GET, when sending request via local apache

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to send a post request with the following code. But the request goes as GET request, instead of POST. How to fix this.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.exampleurl.com',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": true},
    data: {url:'bla',call:"trans"}
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data){
      console.log('succes: '+data);
    }
  });
```

This is the error I am getting
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.com. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

When removed the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin, I am getting a 404 error

Comment: I am using a localhost ..

Comment: Because cross origin is not allowed in browser .. jsonp is a random thing, since json is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97707/discussion-between-gates-and-jaromanda-x).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think, you can use a POST method with jsonp request. jsonp callbacks only for with GET method. Have a look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508198/how-to-use-type-post-in-jsonp-ajax-call) .

Comment: POST with jsonp actually makes no sense, as the mechanism for jsonp simply inserts a `<script>` element into the DOM

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass parameters in `url` attribute when you want to send `POST` request you should use `data` attribute instead, take a look at **[jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)** :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.exampleurl.com',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {q:1, q2:2},
    headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": true},
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data){
      console.log('succes: '+data);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: that makes no difference with dataType:jsonp