# Ajax jquery not calling success even after successfully executing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I need to pass json variable using AJAX. Here is my ajax function:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function emailchkforfrntend()
{
var key='7bc443a2a363b050bc94963baff4b2ac';
var email_id=$("#email_id").val();// email_id->input field id

$.ajax({

    url: "targetURL/example.php",
    type : "post",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data : { "email_id": email_id, "key": key},
    success: function(result){
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('error '+errorThrown);
        alert('status '+textStatus);
        alert('response text '+XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    },
    complete : function(){
        alert('in complete');
    }

})
.done(function(msg) {
    alert('Inside done....'+msg);
if(msg!=0)
{
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);

//var p_fname=obj.p_fname; 

$("#Result_Div").html("<b style='color:blue;'>already existing Member <i class='fa fa-thumbs-o-up'></i></b>");

}
else
{

    $("#Result_Div").html("<b style='color:green;'>New Member <i class='fa fa-thumbs-o-up'></i></b>");

}
});
}
```

HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id='email_id' onkeyup="emailchkforfrntend();">
```

After calling to this function, everytime it is giving call to error function and the control is not calling `.done(function(msg){})`. Also I am getting `Jquery1112016992787341587245_1466413029814 was not called` in first alert of error function. I passed one dummy PHP script to URL, which inserts record into database, to check whether is it calling the URL or not, the call to that PHP is working but still it is calling error function instead of calling success function.

Is there anything that I am missing? what is supposed to be done in order to work this functionality?

Comment: you're probably having an error in your php code then!

Comment: You cannot use `POST` method with jsonp, due to its nature: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4508215/1414562

Comment: @AminJafari PHP code is working fine. Even after call to javascript, by PHP code values are getting inserted into DB.

Comment: @A.Wolff I tried with GET method too, but still the same situation.

Comment: yeah but probably after that it throws the error, it'd be much easier to comment on the problem if you'd post your php code too

Comment: The problem is solved. There was a problem with PHP file. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Trying to help... You said you need send `JSON` variables to `PHP` using `ajax`. I noticed that you are using `JSONP`. Is `JSONP` really necessary?

I wrote a `HTML/JS` code which is working. The code just send data using `AJAX` and execute the callbacks. I'm wondering if in your case the `JSONP` is not affecting the complete callback.

**Result:**

```
Tue Jun 21 2016 15:39:54 GMT-0300 (BRT) Req sent {"email_id":"1","key":"abc"}
Tue Jun 21 2016 15:39:54 GMT-0300 (BRT) Success
Tue Jun 21 2016 15:39:54 GMT-0300 (BRT) Complete {"readyState":4,"responseText":"\n\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\tResult:\n\t\t
\n\t\n","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

**Code:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function log(msg) {
                var dateMsg = (new Date()) + ' ' + msg;
                var $res = $('#result');
                var $o = $('<li>').html(dateMsg);
                $res.append($o);
            }

            function checkEmailFrontEnd(email_id, key) {
                var userdata = {
                    email_id: email_id,
                    key: key
                };
                var opts = {
                    url: 'html.html',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: userdata,
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                        log('Success');
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error){
                        log('Error ' + error);
                    },
                    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                        log('Complete ' + JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                    }
                };
                $.ajax(opts);   
                log('Req sent ' + JSON.stringify(userdata));
            }
            $(function(){
                checkEmailFrontEnd('1', 'abc');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Result:
        <ul id='result'></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is solved. There was a problem with PHP file. Thank you for your help @Valdek Junior