# Getting Error 401 while requesting JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to hit API in javascript but getting error code 401 but on postman it is working fine.

Here is my javascript code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>ABC</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>

        <body onload="test()"> </body>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        function test()
              {
                var credential = '[{"id":"recording", "userId":"administrator", "password":"Expert111"}]'
                $.ajax({
                      url: "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/api/rest/authorize",
                      type: "POST",
                      data: { id: "recording", userId: "administrator", password: "Expert111" },
                       dataType: "jsonp",
                            success: function (result) {
                                switch (result) {
                                    case true:
                                        alert("Success");
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        alert("fail:"+result);
                                }
                            },
                            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            alert("status: " +xhr.status +", ajaxOptions:"+ajaxOptions +",Error:" +thrownError);
                            },
                            //data : credential
                        });
                    };
    </script>
    </html>
```

following is postman snapshot (working fine)

[image]

following is result of request via code:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I notice in your *postman* data you don't include the `callback` or `_` parameters - so, you're not really testing the same thing

Comment: Can you please guide me to include callback or _ parameters?

Comment: Though code seems fine, kindly provide the url so we can try at our end too by running it or set up a dummy url in case you don't wanna share the original.

Comment: I don't know `postman` ... how did you add id, userId and password parameters to the request? ... I think I see an issue ... your `postman` actually does POST the parameters, whereas your ajax is doing a GET request because that's how JSONP is done

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508198/how-to-use-type-post-in-jsonp-ajax-call

Comment: clearly, the API at `http://xx.xx.xx.xx/api/rest/authorize` doesn't accept a GET request, only a POST - therefore you can not use JSONP - and if they don't use CORS, then you wont be able to use JSON datatype with POST method either - you'll need to "proxy" the request through your own site and have your server make a proper POST request to `http://xx.xx.xx.xx/api/rest/authorize`

Comment: if i send JSON in the request, i am getting this error: 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
example.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xx.xx.xx.xx/api/rest/authorize. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Comment: @Touqeer - see my 2 comments just above yours - it turns out CORS is an issue after all

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your server processing authorization, but looks like you didn't pass it. 401 means - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
To my mind, you have to specify Authorization header.

```
var ah = "Basic "+atob("administrator"+":"+"Expert111");
```

And set this as Authorization header like [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13515414/182344).

Moreover, you could check more information about [basic authentication](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) and [encoding to base64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding)

If it isn't help, you could check with [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), what your postman sends to the server and implement your request in the same way.