# Restrict permissions after token-based authentication

Tags: django, authentication, permissions

A site I am working on (using django) requires that users can access a subset of the functionality temporarily by [following a URL sent by email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653903/instant-login-from-email-why-have-so-few-done-this/4654097#4654097), instead of having to login properly (i.e. with username and password).
I am, of course, aware of the potential security issues with this proposal. Therefore, the tokens included in the url are randomly generated and stored on the server (instead of hashing the username or something similar), and expire.

In addition, I would like to restrict the permissions of users accessing the site through such a token URL, so that they can only access some (very limited) information, while their credentials are required for any more substantial actions.

I had implemented this in a rather crude way: Briefly, instead of authenticating the user through the token, it is stored as a session variable, and the few views that recognize the token validate it. 
However, it would be great to have an extended solution: For example, a global `user.has_token` check would be brilliant. I can't imagine, however, how a more elegant solution might be achieved.

So my question is: How would you implement such a system? Is it, for example, possible to temporarily allocate or restrict [permissions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#permissions) in django? Might a custom [middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) be necessary here?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks a lot!

**Edit**: Following the discussion below, I would like to further specify the question: Would it be efficient to assign groups through a middleware on every page view? Would it be feasible to add properties to the user object at run-time (similar to the `user.has_token` example above)?

Answer (score 0):

usings django groups you can restict access

below link gives you the example:

http://bradmontgomery.blogspot.com/2009/04/restricting-access-by-group-in-django.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Groups would be a fixed attribute of the user, though, or could they be changed on the fly?

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? Are you suggesting using `myuser.groups.add(group_x)` and `.remove()` from the middleware, on a per-request basis?