# Access a document in a document library using username and password in query string?

Tags: security, authentication, sharepoint-2007, query-string, moss

Is there a way to provide a username and password through link to document to access a document in a document library in MOSS 2007?

I mean: http://server/DocumentLibrary1/document.xml?username=admin&password=P@ssw0rd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not come across anything in SharePoint that would allow you to do something like that. And since that is a document and not a server side page, you would need to create a custom HTTP handler to do something like that.

However, doing something insecure like that is not recommend. For instance, see [Is a https query string secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323200/is-a-https-query-string-secure)