# Posting user data in a URL

Tags: security, url

Is it unwise to do this? The thing I'm talking about is username and password being passed to a processing file, like this:

```
echo'<script>location.href="process.php?u='.$_POST['username'].'&p='.md5($_POST['password']).'"</script>';
```

This is after the username and password has been validated. Could this somehow be intercepted maliciously? Or is this a safe enough thing to do?

Comment: no please don't do that.It's malicious...

Comment: To a computer a MD5 hash, string of characters or whatever encryption is equilivant to a password. The receivind end will be happy as a alcololic with a GIN or a Whisky or a Vodka. To them it is the same as meths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***DO NOT DO THIS***

There, now that we've cleared that up, allow me to explain...

What you're essentially doing is sending this data to the user in the clear.  Even if you're using SSL encryption for the transport, it's still a big risk.  It's not "rendering in the browser" but that doesn't matter.  It's still being sent to the browser.  And even if in this particular case you don't run into any issues, it's a bad habit to build.

You might even ask, "But I'm using `md5()` so the password is obscured, right?"

Wrong.

The text is obscured, yes.  But you're delivering the obscured version of the text to the client and then keying off of that text.  Which means you're still displaying an effective password for all to see.

If the password is "correcthorsebatterystaple" then you don't want to display it in plain text because that would give somebody the password, right?  (In fact, you don't even want to *store* it in plain text.  Anywhere.  You, as the site admin, don't even want to *know* or have *any* way to find out the text of the password.  If you can, someone else can.)  Right.

So, instead, you obscure the password as "elughwelfguweliurgnswfglwerlgu" which your code interprets as the password.  So you can display that, right?  Wrong.  Because now, by accepting "elughwelfguweliurgnswfglwerlgu" as the password from the client, you've made "elughwelfguweliurgnswfglwerlgu" into *the plain text password that your system accepts*.  So the obscuring of the text does nothing.

In short, never ever deliver a password to anybody in any form.  Your application should *receive* passwords as input, but *never* produce them as output in *any* way.

Comment: I wish I could give you +million. But you get +1.

Comment: You forgot to mention that a good feature of good security is that a session is not repeatable by another.

Answer (score 4):

That is a very bad thing to do. All user data should be stored in `$_SESSION`, or, you should set a validation cookie and use that for authentication.

Additionally, you should never "keep" the user's password. You should hash it and store the hash in the database, then check the posted password against the hash on login.

Additionally, your hash should be one way, and you shouldn't be able to retrieve or view the user's original password.

Finally, MD5 is horribly defeated. It is no longer remotely secure, and can be demolished by a rainbow table attack. You should look into something much stronger and slower (slow is good) such as [bcrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/420001).

Answer (score 1):

NO NO NO

When a person enters a password to set up an account (or change password) use POST and SSL.

Otherwise the password is a one way street without either MD5 or plain text in the URL.

When a user logs in give them a session. This can expire and therefore become invalid.

As to be intercepted - You can just get a packet sniffer

Comment: He isn't talking about the initial sending of credentials via a login form, he's talking about sending the user info back to the browser, and sending it via url parameters on all future requests. Additionally, MD5 is severely outdated, and should not be recommended.

Comment: @Josh - He was thinking of changing the URLor the window via Javascript. Hence the `location.href` bit. That could be anything from setting up the account to ....

Answer (score 1):

> Could this somehow be intercepted maliciously?

Yes. Anyone can look at the source of your page and see the username and the md5 hash of the password. It will also show up in the URL of the browser when the page redirects for the user.

Could it be intercepted via a man-in-the-middle attack? Not necessarily. If you are using HTTPS, the query string will be encrypted in the SSL packet along with the rest of the request. If you're not using HTTPS, anyone will be able to see the query string which, so you know, makes GET just as secure as POST when looking at man-in-the-middle attacks.

Here's a good comparison of how GET can be less secure in HTTPS environment: [Is an HTTPS query string secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323200/is-a-https-query-string-secure)