# Hide url in the address bar using .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url, redirect

When a user click post,after filling a form,it post the form datas into a php from where it is sent (redirected) to another url.

But the form has confidential datas,that is been shown in the address bar while redirecting.

The url is seen as http://payment.kkl.com?token.jsp?id=ajsjs&password=pefwhkewhxxx

data is being posted to a php file using post method.From the php ,this datas are again encrypted and along with some raw data it is rediredted to an external url as I have shown.This external url has parameters that I dont want to expose
i  need to hide the id and password,the url in the address bar should be shown with out the id and password..Anyway to do this using htaccesS??

Answer (score 2):

Make use of **`POST`** method on your `<form>` to pass information to the other page.

Definitely **`.htaccess`** is not the solution here.

Comment: See I use the post data,so that the data is being posted to a php file.From the php ,this datas are again encrypted and along with some raw data it is rediredted to an external url as I have show.This external url has parameters that I dont want to expose..

Comment: Do you have control over the `external url` ? If you are passing the data in an `encrypted` form , why do you worry ?

Comment: @user3079558: i think you may look at `RESTful webservice` for this. look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer or search for `REST` web service on google

Comment: no the encrypted data,along with some raw data,in a format  that is accepted by the external url.so i cannot simply encrypt it

Comment: Is your external URL using SSL i.e. (https) if so you don't have to worry.

Comment: yes i use ssl,but it still shows up in the url from which anyone could copy out the parameteres,like password and all those things.

Comment: Have a look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323200/is-an-https-query-string-secure