# SSL certificate will encrypt the query string values used in my MVC 3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ssl, encryption

I want to encrypt the query string values used in my MVC3 application. If i implement SSL certificate, whether all the parameters passed with url in encrypted form or not. The application is already completed, now its running appscan testing, so its very tough to encrypt and decrypt manually the query string.

Answer (score 1):

As per answer given in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323200/is-an-https-query-string-secure)

Yes, it is. But using `GET` for sensitive data is a bad idea for several reasons:

Mostly HTTP referrer leakage (an external image in the target page might leak the password[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323200/is-an-https-query-string-secure))
Password will be stored in server logs (which is obviously bad)
History caches in browsers
Therefore, even though Querystring is secured it's not recommended to transfer sensitive data over querystring.

Comment: Thanks Nilesh, Currently I implemented self signed SSL . Can we able to encrypt the query strings by using self signed, or its required authorized certificate.

Comment: we cant encrypt using SSL but The entire text of an HTTPS session is secured by SSL. That includes the query and the headers.