# encrypt and decrypt query string in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Somebody can tell me what the  best way to encrypt and decrypt query string?
What algorithm is best?
Symmetric algorithm,
Assymetric algorithm,
Digital signature,
Or other algorithm that I don't know
Please help

Comment: What's the source? What's the purpose? Is it for internally produced urls, or to authenticate referrals from third party?

Comment: Also, what qualifies as the `best`? Is it the fastest, is it the most complex (hardest to crack) is it the one that produces the most beautiful strings? Besides I think this question is far better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ than for so.

Comment: For transmit  important information

Comment: What is faster? What is hardest to crack?I want know

Comment: You didn't answer my questions. We understand that the information is important to you, but who's transmitting it? Who's generating the urls? Do you need tamper-production to avoid that someone changes data, or completely hide what data is transmitted?

Comment: I think there is not a good general answer - because it depends on the scenario. What exactly is it that you want to do? I.e. it _could_ be an option to just use SSL/TLS - because that includes the encryption of the query string. However, that is not a best practice; please see [Is an HTTPS query string secure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323200/is-an-https-query-string-secure)

Comment: I want completely hide query string

Comment: you cant 'hide' querystring but u can encrypt the querystring. please check below..

Comment: _Why_ do you want to hide your query strings? Have you used obscene words as database identifiers? Do you want to avoid people guessing identifiers? Is this an attempt to avoid implementing proper access security?

Answer (score 0):

For symmetric encryption, check out the MSDN doc and examples:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.Aes
System.Security.Cryptography.DES
System.Security.Cryptography.RC2
System.Security.Cryptography.Rijndael
System.Security.Cryptography.TripleDES
```

For asymmetric encryption, check out the MSDN doc and examples:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.DSA
System.Security.Cryptography.ECDiffieHellman
System.Security.Cryptography.ECDsa
System.Security.Cryptography.RSA
```

**Example :**

you can change these

```
static readonly string PasswordHash = "P@@Sw0rd";
static readonly string SaltKey = "S@LT&KEY";
static readonly string VIKey = "@1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8";
```

*Encrypt:*

```
public static string Encrypt(string plainText)
        {
            byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

            byte[] keyBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(PasswordHash, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SaltKey)).GetBytes(256 / 8);
            var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged() { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros };
            var encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(VIKey));

            byte[] cipherTextBytes;

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                    cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    cryptoStream.Close();
                }
                memoryStream.Close();
            }
            return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
        }
```

*Decrypt:*

```
public static string Decrypt(string encryptedText)
        {
            byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
            byte[] keyBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(PasswordHash, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SaltKey)).GetBytes(256 / 8);
            var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged() { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, Padding = PaddingMode.None };

            var decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(VIKey));
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);
            var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
            byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];

            int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
            memoryStream.Close();
            cryptoStream.Close();
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount).TrimEnd("\0".ToCharArray());
        }
```

**Usage of Above:**

```
string strvalue=Encrypt(someid);
Response.Redirect("yourpage.aspx?id=strvalue");
```

**On Redirected Page:**

```
if(Request.QueryString["id"]!=null)
{
    string decryptval=Decrypt(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString());
}
```

[View other Encryption Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string)

Hope this helps!