# Facebook 'code' parameter as part of query string for OAuth authentication

Tags: java, php, facebook, security, oauth-2.0

Even though Authorization Code is short-lived comparing to Authorization token, isn't there a vulnerability in sending it in 'GET' as a query string? Isn't it similar to sending password using GET method?

In other words, after authentication facebook redirects user's browser to mysite.com sending the authorization code as a query string. Isn't it un-encrypted? middle man who is listening to your packets can read it and use it to highjack your session (session at mysite.com)?

Say,

1. I blocked the redirect (after getting the 'code' from facebook) on
   my browser side (using some browser add-on/plug-in)
2. I copied the complete redirect URL
   (www.mysite.com?code=AQCOtAV..blah) and trying it from a different
   browser.
3. the request will go through and mysite.com will contact facebook
   with inbound Authorization Code along with secretKey and clientId
   and Authenticate and generate Authorization token (I haven't really
   tried this step : step 3)

I know I am missing something here. Kindly help me out.

Comment: What vulnerability? What happens that should not be allowed to happen?

Comment: You are sending Authorization code over the network in unencrypted way. If there is any middleman listening to your packets, they will get the Authorization code and will be able to hijack the your session, right?

Comment: You're absolutely wrong. Please read the authorization code grant part in the specification. As a summary, code is securely exchanged for a token by the remote web application using a backchannel that you cannot see. Embedded applications use a different scenario.

Comment: Thanks Zólyomi.
I understand that.. I am talking about one step before that, where user's browser gets the redirect (redirect to mysite.com) from facebook.... that time, when users browser send the 'authorization code' to mysite.com its unencrypted.. right?

Comment: Right, the authorization code is received as a GET parameter, but using a HTTPS connection. It's still possible to fetch it from the browser, but you need appropriate client_id/secret and redirect_uri to exchange it for a token, so only the appropriate webapp can do that. I don't see the vulnerability here. The specification considers a lot of different attack methods, please read it.

Comment: @ZólyomiIstván is correct. The authorization code is not secret, nor does it have to be (if a flow with a client secret is used). Things are different if an access token is sent that way, as in the Implicit Grant. Read the spec at http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749.

Comment: And in addition to what @ZólyomiIstván already said, the authorization code is a one time code. As soon as you exchange it, it is useless. Even if a hacker already managed to exchange it before you did, you can detect that situation (and so can the authorization server), and the user can revoke their authorization.

Comment: @ZólyomiIstván Thanks! "authorization code is received as a GET parameter, but using a HTTPS connection" this answers my question.
When I asked the OP I knew I was missing something... I just found out which piece was missing.. all this time I was thinking that query parameter sent in GET request is unencrypted and will appear as plain text (even if its https)... Guess what, I was wrong all this time! Thanks again.

Comment: I downvoted for the unclear question, unrealistic security assumptions and the RTFM-like nature. I'm willing to remove the downvote, but the site lets me do so only after you edit the question. Maybe you could clarify the question and summarize all this into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Zólyomi for pointing out that even though the authorization code is sent across as a query parameter, its using HTTPS to send.

**Answer:**
The query string sent across https is secure. No matter which http method GET or POST you are using, its encrypted and no middleman can listen to it. More info.
[Is an HTTPS query string secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323200/is-an-https-query-string-secure)

However for numerous other reason sending the password in query string is not a good practice (password may appear in server logs as plain text as part of the URL etc). But that doesn't apply here because the Authorization code is a short lived one and its useless once its exchanged for the Authorization token.