# Using Google reCaptcha always shows 'incorrect-captcha-sol'

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

I'm trying to use Google reCaptcha on my website and after following several tutorials, I'm using as follow on my HTML page:

```
<section class="row" id="Contact">
        <div class="col-full">
             <form method="post" action="contact.php">
                <input name="sender" placeholder="Name" size="30"><br><br>
                <input name="senderEmail" placeholder="Email" size="30"><br><br>
                <textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea><br><br>
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdFOQcTAAAAABKsku3bD6Mp3HuGYNDRN1tLlSkw"></div><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
</section>
```

With the following within the `<head>` tag:

```
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

The form loads the following PHP script as shown on [Google's tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/wiki/FAQ):

```
<?php

require_once('recaptchalib.php');

echo "<pre> _POST: =========\n";
print_r($_POST);
echo "\n=========\n</pre>";

$privatekey = "privatekey";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                             $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                             $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                             $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
if (!$resp->is_valid)
{
  die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
    "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
}
```

?>

The problem is I always get the error `incorrect-captcha-sol` and can't understand why. the output I get from the PHP script is:

```
 _POST: =========
Array
(
 [g-recaptcha-response] => 03AHJ_VusLbTZVbhMBH2-cyOdbM81IoG7ShDtTmyVa8e34PbghyKaRYnrb4bbeuPoJXFa-2sD5B-UIOWq_zClya-VOtq8iLHXBkAR0PrElQYiQjKTm2POkjci43-yEaenh1tu_M4vKsjJGswKFlVs6IdlWhdVaMdznLBeutgHjiHRBy7fzAi0It0x5IadwMxAqVpmG7F1gRvUcQmakij4ObTqPUK4lPdc84HkkKmY62uJ45d8DwKSeR2ifRg6wL9JFxpcZkjSp4oIlltin2uCMiBDU58QQQLLKPJuSKcmm-N5p7OEt7E6gc4UZyTLpKrJ-9mMUusvLpixwFHop0e5155vEZssxzu6Zizo-LyB1mX3XOrQ8LEceydssgLvl9gJBC4f9zDBKPQdLmjfxVKdPCXLtUZVNbMDYe7cNL7gsgwJC-hLbZYTh6UV1nUdKnFnkHAACjI7M28hpKWdiyIwcJ5UAzTMPfIllMw
)

=========
```

Why don't I have `recaptcha_challenge_field` or `recaptcha_response_field` fields on my POST and how can I solve it?

Comment: @AndreaLigios Yes, I am sure that I used the right private key.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27681128/1654265

Answer (score 3):

The code I used for my recaptcha is as follows:

This goes in the header:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

This goes where you want the actual recaptcha to be:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="PUBLIC_KEY_HERE"></div>
```

You can add this to the div to change the theme: `data-theme="theme"`

And this is the PHP script:

```
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
$captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
if(!$captcha){
    //Captcha hasn't been checked
}
$response=json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=SECRET_KEY_HERE&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), true);
if($response['success'] == false){
    //Captcha incorrect
}
else {
    //Success code here
}
```

Comment: Well, `$response['success']` seems to be always false when I try that.

Comment: That's very strange, it works perfectly for me. Make sure you have put in your public and secret keys properly. If that still does not work try in a brand new file to see if the results are any different.

Comment: Why this works and official GOOGLE code doesn't? This is some weird magic. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you do not have an `else` option after you check the answer. You check if its wrong but there is nothing to tell it what to do if the user got it right. Try adding something like this:

```
if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." . "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
}
else {
    //Code for success here
}
```

Comment: I just didn't upload the rest of the code, since it is irrelevant to the problem and the `$resp->is_valid` always returns false as I always get an error.

Comment: Are you using the new checkbox recaptcha? If so I can post the code I used for mine.

Comment: I think I'm using the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

I use Google New reCaptcha

`https://github.com/google/recaptcha` Official Code

It is StandAlone package. It works with php great.

after failed captcha i use jquery code to reload capctha

`grecaptcha.reset();`

because recapctha response expire after validation and captcha does not reload so it will send **expired response again and again** until you don't reload page to get new Captcha code.

Validation code

```
require('/path/to/recaptcha/autoload.php');

$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret);
$resp = $recaptcha->verify($gRecaptchaResponse, $remoteIp);
if ($resp->isSuccess()) {
} else { $errors = $resp->getErrorCodes();
foreach ($errors as $code) {
echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">$code</div>";
}
echo "<p><strong>Note:</strong> Error code <tt>missing-input-response</tt> may mean the user just didn't complete the reCAPTCHA.</p>";
}
```